# Where is "texmf" on a Windows install?

Tags: packages, windows, texmf

On UNIX you have the `texmf` folder in your home directory where you store packages you've installed yourself, but where is that folder on a Windows install?

<sub>Yeah, I know that if you use MiKTeX then you don't need to worry about it since it installs needed packages on-the-fly, but I'm still interested. =)</sub>

Comment: Are you using MiKTeX or TeX Live or w32tex or any else?

Comment: @Leo Liu: MiKTeX.

Comment: See also, [installing - How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) & [What are TeXLive's four different texmf folders? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/what-are-texlives-four-different-texmf-folders);

Answer (score 23, accepted):

'texmf' is not the exact directory name, but refer to the root paths of the TeX distribution. There are often more than one 'texmf' tree, and they are often not called 'texmf'. In MiKTeX, you can find all texmf tree in MiKTeX's option (Start menu -> MiKTeX -> Maintenance -> settings):

[image]

Comment: Does a Linux install also apply multiple root paths?

Comment: Yes. TeX Live 2010 has `texmf`, `texmf-dist`, `texmf-var`, `texmf-local`, `texmf-config` and `~/.texlive2010/texmf-var`, `~/.texlive2010/texmf-config`, for both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 16):

You could type at the command prompt:

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

Alternatively:

```
kpsewhich -expand-var '$TEXMFHOME'
```

While on my Linux system, it returns `/home/stefan/texmf`, on Windows it may return something like `C:/Users/Gablin/texmf` depending on where your Windows user profile is.

The syntax of [kpsewhich](http://texblog.net/hypertext-help/latex-tools/kpsewhich/) may vary depending on the system, for example regarding the quotes or dashes. Type `kpsewhich --help`.