# What are TeXLive's four different texmf folders?

Tags: texlive, texmf, folders

Could someone please explain to me what the purpose of the four different texmf folders are in Mac? E.g. there is:

1. `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf`
2. `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config`
3. `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist`
4. `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var`

Also, when installing fonts and packages, do I place them in `/texmf` or `/texmf-dist`?

Comment: You can find all search pathes by `kpsexpand '$TEXMF'` and only the local search path by `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'`

Comment: Refer to Section 
**2.3 Overview of the predeﬁned texmf trees** of the [TeX Live documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html).

Answer (score 26):

OK, given the helpful comments to your query, here's a discussion of how the various `texmf` folders map into the "official" nomenclature of the TeXLive tree (set in all-caps):

- .../texmf: TEXMFMAIN  -- "The tree which holds vital parts of the system such as configuration files, helper scripts, and program documentation."
- .../texmf-dist: TEXMFDIST -- "The tree which holds the main set of macro packages, fonts, etc."
- .../texmf-var: TEXMFSYSVAR -- "The (site-wide) tree used by texconfig-sys, updmap-sys and fmtutil-sys, and also by tlmgr, to store (cached) runtime data such as format files and generated map files."
- .../texmf-config: TEXMFSYSCONFIG -- "The (site-wide) tree used by the utilities texconfig-sys, updmap-sys, and fmtutil-sys to store modified configuration data."

Separately, if you have a LOCALTEXMF directory tree, TeXLive expects to find it at `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`, unless you edit the configuration file `/usr/local/texlive/`*year* `/texmf.cnf` and provide an alternate location. If you do so, be sure to run `texhash` to update the filename database.

Comment: no, `texmf-local` is always at `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. It is _before_ the year wise distributions

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks for catching this mistake; I've removed the year part from the final paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Also, `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` is for *system-wide* local additions, not individual user local additions, which are normally placed in TEXMFHOME (on Linux systems, standardly `/home/<user>/texmf`; on a Mac `/Users/Library/texmf`).  If you have a single user system, there's not much advantage to installing local packages in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`, I think.

Comment: @Alan Munn: files in `/home/<user>/texmf` are searched recursively which is slower than using the ls-R file of `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`

Comment: @Herbert Surely you'd have to have a lot of stuff in there for that difference to be noticeable? (And you can run `texhash` on the local dir too, right?)

Answer (score 11):

the `TeX Directory Structure` (TDS) is documented in http://tug.org/tds/tds.html#Top_002dlevel-directories. That is the structure below `texmf-dist` and also
below `.../texmf-local/` and `~/texmf/`.

The directories for TeXLive are documented in http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-100002.2