# How to automate using biber in MiKTeX-TeXworks

Tags: compiling, miktex, biber, tools, texworks

I have MikTeX 2.9, 32-bit, Windows 7, all the latest updates are there. I'm using TeXworks ( `pdflatex` + `makeindex` + `bibtex`).

When I use `biblatex` package with option `[backend=biber]` I have no bibliography printed at all. If I run `biber.exe` over my file manually, then everything works fine.

My question is: How can I set up TeXworks, so it uses `biber.exe` when needed (i.e. I would like to have`pdflatex` + `makeindex` + `biber` typesetting)? I did not find any manual regarding the case. If there is such manual, could anybody point me out to it?

Comment: @percusse I guess the point is the MiKTeX adds 'pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX' to the 'Typeset' menu of TeXworks.

Comment: @percusse MiKTeX isn't an editor, it's a TeX distribution on Windows. It includes the command `texify` which runs (pdf)LaTeX, BibTeX and MakeIndex in a single command.

Comment: MikTeX is a project. It includes TeXWorks, and adds pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX typesetting. When I use this typesetting in connection to backend=biber option of biblatex, then the bibliography is not printed until manual run of biber.exe over my file. How shall I "tell" TeXWorks to run biber automatically when needed?

Comment: @JosephWright I don't know what I'm saying nevermind. I was thinking about TeXnicCenter for some reason,

Comment: `texify` needs to have a update to be able to process `biber` instead of `bibtex`. But you can build a batch file calling `pdflatex`, `biber` etc. Then you can add the call of this batch in `TeXworks`, for example `pdfLaTeX+Makeindex+biber`.

Answer (score 13):

Let me suggest an other tool.

Every document has its own requirements regarding the compilation. As you wrote you need `pdflatex`, `makeindex` and `biber`. My recommended tool allows the setting of the compilation out of the `tex` file. The tool is named [arara](https://github.com/cereda/arara)

Next to the short online introduction the author Paulo Cereda provides a complete manual which can be downloaded here: [arara at github (download part)](https://bintray.com/cereda/arara/installers/3.0)

`arara` provided and installer with some predefined rules. Based on your requirement you can setup you main tex file header as follows:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { draft: true }
% arara: makeindex: {  style: stylefile.ist }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
```

If you need only one compilation e.g. pdflatex you can comment the other assignments with a previous `!`:

```
% !arara: pdflatex: { draft: true }
% !arara: makeindex: {  style: stylefile.ist }
% !arara: biber
% !arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
```

The different compilation rules have more options and can be modified for your specification easily.

The integration and usage of the tool `arara` in TeXworks is described in the manual in section 4.1.

Comment: The suggested order of execution could lead to incorrect results. `makeindex` should be called after the result of `biber` has been compiled by (pdf)LaTeX, and in general one should not run `makeindex` after the first run of LaTeX (e.g., the table of contents should be longer than 1 page.

Comment: @Guido: In general I agree with you. In your case we need two draft runs before and after makeindex.

Answer (score 12):

A little bit late, and the solution has been mentioned before in this thread, but I had just the same problem. 
A quick solution to use pdfLaTeX with `biber` in TeXworks is to use a batch file.

Create the file `pdflatex+biber.bat` in your MiKTeX directory, in the subfolder `/miktex/bin/`, with the following content:

```
miktex-pdftex.exe -synctex=1 -undump=pdflatex "%1"
biber.exe "%2"
miktex-pdftex.exe -synctex=1 -undump=pdflatex "%1"
```

Now open the typesetting editor of TeXworks and add a new setting. Name it appropriate (e.g. "pdfLatex+Biber") and give the path to your batchfile (`.../miktex/bin/pdflatex+biber.bat`). Add two arguments: `$fullname` and `$basename`.

That's it, works fine for me and I think, the solution can be adopted to other situations, where more/other programs have to be involved in the typesetting process.

Comment: Putting your own batch file into the main MiKTeX tree is dangerous, see [Purpose of local texmf trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/purpose-of-local-texmf-trees). For MikTeX then: [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

Comment: BTW Why did you set all commands into one line? Put them into 3 lines and the code is far better readable.

Comment: Thanks for mention the fact about the main MiKTeX tree :-) I didn't had that in mind... 

Formatting: I didn't found an explanation for setting up Biber with MiKTeX anywhere on the web, and when I was happy with my solution I didn't care about the formatting. But you're right, and I changed the code above :-)

Comment: @Speravir So is it fine to put the batch files in a local texmf tree? Which folder would be a good choice? `texmf/bin`?

Comment: @Schneider Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 7):

In the `pdflatex + makeindex + bibtex`-typesetting-configuration that you describe, TeXworks relies on `texify`. You can tell texify to run `biber` instead of `bibtex` via the environment variable `BIBTEX` ([texify documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texifying.html)).

Normally you can set the Variable here: 
`Control Panel --> System --> Advanced system settings --> Advanced --> Environment Variables --> New`.
However, I would not recommend doing that, as it will break any legacy project you might be using with bibtex.

Instead, I'd recommand setting up a Batch-File:

```
@set BIBTEX=biber
@texify %*
```

Then you set up a new typesetting in TeXworks. It should get the same Arguments as the `pdflatex + makeindex + bibtex`-Typesetting and the Batch-File as a command.

But there is another caveat: With texify might not reliably detect that it needs to re-run after biber changed things. You can re-run the whole thing manually, when in doubt. There is also [this workaround](http://miktex.10937.n7.nabble.com/pdf-texify-using-biber-instead-of-bibtex-td7420.html) that relies on inserting some code into your main TeX-File.

As you can see, this seems to be quite experimental the other solutions with different tools or editors might be more easy.

Comment: I tried `set BIBTEX=biber` and `set BIBTEX=full/path/to/biber.exe `, as suggested [here](https://miktex-users.narkive.com/gVVlkEcr/miktex-pdf-texify-using-biber-instead-of-bibtex#post4), but none seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

Compiling a `*TeX` document can be involved - for example, if you wish to produce an index you have to run something more but the simple `pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex` (or `biber` in your case). Therefore, I chose eventually to use [`latexmk`](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/)  which takes care of all this automatically - so far it didn't let down!

I'm not familiar with the windows setting, but I guess you could set the editor to use `latexmk` for the compilation of a document.

Answer (score 0):

@benne08 solution worked perfectly from the texmf-local as instructed by @speravir and is the easiest option to use I found from all sources. The following is more obvious and simpler to set up for one off testing.

Add `Biber` using `|TeXworks|Edit>Preferences…>|[Typesetting]|` finding .../miktex/bin/biber.exe

Add `$basename` as an argument. You can add `–U` and `–u` if you want it to input and the output in utf8 encoding (These utf8 arguments I haven’t checked personally).

Then run the individual steps e.g.: `PdfLaTex` -> `Biber` -> `PdfLaTex` from the typesetting bar.

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864), if you think the answers for TeXworks there needs improvement, please go ahead and edit it.

Comment: The entry was excellent and esentially identical with provided graphics (I missed it due to the title). I made a slight clarafication about finding the executable that was not self evident.

Comment: Mhhh, did you really find it necessary to provide the full path to Biber, normally I would expect that to not be necessary. Biber would probably be installed in a directory that is in the path.

Comment: Duhhhh! I did a quick edit based late last night on your suggestion and realised later :-( I should have tested rather than interpreted. Thanks fo the nudge, I will re-edit.