# Using \ExecuteBibliographyOptions causes bibliography not to appear

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm writing my thesis and trying to get separate reference indexing for each chapter. Working off a friend's template, it seems I'm looking for the `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` options. However, when I add that line, no bibliography is produced. The warning I get is:

```
biblatex Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):
(biblatex)                debuggingbib1-blx
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Tried a BUNCH of things. Switching to biber did not work, probably because I'm using texworks and did not implement the [arara hack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69705/how-to-automate-using-biber-in-miktex-texworks). Note again, it works fine (sans my options) if I comment out the executebibliographyoptions line. Thoughts?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=nature]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{url=false,refsection=chapter,maxnames=99}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblib.bib} 
@article{Novick1957,
author = {Novick, A and Weiner, M},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Dropbox/Papers Mendeley/Novick, Weiner - 1957 - Enzyme induction as an all-or-none phenomenon.pdf:pdf},
journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of \ldots},
pages = {553--566},
title = {{Enzyme induction as an all-or-none phenomenon}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC528498/},
year = {1957}
}
\end{filecontents} 

\addbibresource{biblib.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap:introduction}

\section{A brief history of non-genetic variability}
Although observations of cell-to-cell expression variability are relatively new, with one prescient exception \cite{Novick1957},

\section{bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the warning? Open a command line/terminal window go to directory where you latex file is and type and run `bibtex debuggingbib1-blx`. Alterntively, change the `backend` to `biber`.  Compile with  pdflatex and then `biber debugging bib`.

Comment: I thought when I run pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTeX this is called, no? Running it manually did work! But it's really annoying. Every citation I add it asks me to repeat this process. Any way to automate that? As noted, I *have* tried to get biber to work, no luck.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations to see how to configure TeXworks to work with biber.  By the way it is more productive not to compile every single time you add a single citation (does not matter if you do it manually from the command line of clicking a button in your editor.

Comment: Before posting I did read that guide to try to get biber to work. No luck with that. Even if I got it to work though, why should it require multiple steps? With one click I can integrate and create a nice latex document, references and all, using \bibliographystyle{plain} and \bibliography{<my_lib.bib>} without using biber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I just wasted a day on this, figured I'd post my findings and solution. In order of the key steps..

1. I switched from TeXWorks to TeXStudio which doesn't require a workaround / multiple clicks to build the pdf and the bibliography with biber, although as pointed out there [are hacks for this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations) as linked above.
2. I set the options->configure->build->bibliography default to biber.
3. When I built the file above at this point, it still didn't work. I got the error message Error: Command crashed: biber.exe. I got similar errors executing biber at the command line, e.g., 'process ended unexpectedly' with a RAM address listed.
4. Assuming the problem was the version of biber, I subsequently installed many versions of biber from their [official site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/): versions 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, and experimental. 1.9 consistently gave me the error message above. The remaining versions executed without error, but a) complained about disagreement with biblatex control version, and b) did not produce a bibliography.
5. Finally, I installed the [CTAN hosted version of biber](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber/binaries/Windows), and that solved all problems. Code above executes using biber backend WITH the \ExecuteBibliographyOptions line present.

If it isn't clear, I'm a complete newb, so I may have missed something here. Not sure why the original miktex version of biber didn't work, nor any of the official ones. Hope this helps someone out. Cheers.

Comment: Since no-one else has mentioned it, AFAIK the versions of biblatex and biber are in lockstep: you must use the version of biber which corresponds to your version of biblatex. There is a table in the biblatex documentation which specifies which is which.