# Automating Biber in TeXworks

Tags: miktex, biber, texworks

I'm using `miktex` portable with the included `TeXworks` editor. I need to compile a document using:

```
pdfLaTex - Biber - pdfLaTex
```

If I run the three commands individually, they work fine. However, when I create a new tool to run all `3` together, the Biber part seems to get skipped, I cannot find any information about Biber in the console output.

Also, I've noticed that when I run `pdfLaTex` by itself, it creates an aux and bcf file, but when I run all 3 together, those files are not created. I know `Biber` needs the bcf file to run, so I suspect this may be part of the problem, though I don't know what is causing it.

This is the confuguration I have for the tool that I created in `TeXworks`:

[image]

Running the three programs individually works, but it would be nice if all 3 could run together. Any ideas of what could be wrong here?

Comment: [How to automate using biber in MiKTeX-TeXworks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69705/106162) has some suggestions.

Comment: The main question is if texify can call nowadays biber (I never use texify, imho it is a pain).

Comment: Use `latexmk` or `arara` instead. I think if you want to use Biber with `texify` you need to change some environment variables.