# Automatic prefix in index for words with accented characters

Tags: indexing, accents

When generating an index with French words, I need to add a prefix to accentuated words so they they get listed in alphabetical order:

```
\index{saintete@sainteté}
\index{ame@âme}
```

Is there a way to have this done automatically?

Comment: Not with MakeIndex that's irremediably old-fashioned and deals only with Latin unaccented characters. With Xindy it should be possible.

Comment: `\newcommand\saintete{sainteté\index{saintete@sainteté}}`..?

Comment: @jon: I'd have to do that for hundreds of keywords then.

Comment: I figured; but this is another reason why technical/special terminology should always be encoded in macros (easy to say that at the wrong time, I know).  The advantage, however, is that you can do things like: `\newcommand{\saintete}[1][]{sainteté\index{saintete@sainteté!#1}}` and then have in your text, main and sub-entries like `\saintete` and `\saintete[typologie de]`  very easily.

Comment: Well I don't really do my indexes this way actually (not for this book at least). Quite a few words I use as index do not actually occur in the text.

Comment: If you want to stick with makeindex, are yiu using pdflatex/inputenc or xe/lua-latex, the accented letter handling is completely different in those cases

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Ah so you won't be accepting my answer then:-) still it may be useful to someone...

Comment: in luatex it must be possible to do something similar to mine but instead of active inputenc characters just process the string with a lua regexp string replace to replace accented characters by the base

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Xindy instead of MakeIndex the sorting seems to be correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-L french]
\begin{document}
ame\index{ame}
âme\index{âme}
année\index{année}
cote\index{cote}
côte\index{côte}
coté\index{coté}
côté\index{côté}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Recall that `imakeidx` with Xindy requires `-shell-escape` (or running `texindy` manually).

[image]

Comment: What are your exact command lines for compiling this example with Xindy? Thanks

Comment: @pluton Just `pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>`

Comment: That is strange. I've been trying that several times and it does not work. On windows, I got a "'texindy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" error message. I have to investigate.

Comment: @pluton: I'm guessing you need to install xindy.

Comment: @egreg: That's pretty cool. I generate two indexes for that book, but only one has this requirement, and the other one has quite complex settings. Is there a way to keep using makeindex for one index and use xindy for the other?

Comment: @ℝaphink --- I just realized that I certainly have to go through the following post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex

Comment: @ℝaphink Don't give the `texindy` option to the package, but use `\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-L french,...]` for defining the index which you want to use Xindy for.

Answer (score 6):

Sticking with `makeindex` and `pdftex` you can do something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\let\oldindex\index
\makeatletter

\def\index#1{%
  {\let\IeC\@firstofone   \let\^\@empty
   \let\'\@empty
   \let\`\@empty
   \let\'\@empty
   \let\@tabacckludge\@gobble
  \protected@xdef\tmp{#1\unexpanded{@#1}}}%
  \oldindex{\tmp}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

ame\index{ame}
âme\index{âme}
année\index{année}
cote\index{cote}
côte\index{côte}
coté\index{coté}
côté\index{côté}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces an idx file

```
\indexentry{ame@ame}{1}
\indexentry{ame@\IeC {\^a}me}{1}
\indexentry{annee@ann\IeC {\'e}e}{1}
\indexentry{cote@cote}{1}
\indexentry{cote@c\IeC {\^o}te}{1}
\indexentry{cote@cot\IeC {\'e}}{1}
\indexentry{cote@c\IeC {\^o}t\IeC {\'e}}{1}
```

and output

[image]

Comment: That looks like a very interesting alternative.