# Imakeidx fails on LuaLaTeX

Tags: natbib, imakeidx, lualatex-dev

I had to switch from `makeindex` to `imakeidx` due to this [accents related issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118551/135685), but I get the error `Missing \begin{document}`. I'm running `lualatex-dev.exe` in TeXnicCenter, the parameters of `makeindex.exe` are `"%tm.idx" -t "%tm.ilg" -o "%tm.ind"`, everything is updated as of today. Please see my example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx} % Putting here xindy as an option doesn't seem to matter.
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-l hungarian -c utf8] % I don't know if encoding option is necessary.
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing

Egy hegylánc közepén keresztültörve tetejéről talapjáig, négymértföldnyi messzeségben;
kétoldalt hatszáz lábtól háromezerig emelkedő magas, egyenes sziklafalak, közepett az
óvilág óriás folyama, az Ister: a Duna. A ránehezülő víztömeg törte-e magának e kaput,
vagy a föld alatti tűz repeszté kétfelé a hegyláncot? Neptun alkotta-e ezt, vagy Volcán?
Vagy ketten együtt? A mű Istené! Ahhoz hasonlót még a mai istenutánzó kor vaskezű emberei
sem bírnak alkotni.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: natbib redefines \makeindex and then it not longer can take an optional argument (and it fails with pdflatex too). Load natbib earlier and hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load `natbib` before `imakeidx`, but also change the call of `\makeindex`, because `-l` and `-c` are wrong and should be `-L` and `-C` respectively.

Use `lualatex-dev -shell-escape` in order to get automatic generation of the index. Otherwise, run `texindy` and not `makeindex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{imakeidx} % Putting here xindy as an option doesn't seem to matter.
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-L hungarian -C utf8]
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing

Egy hegylánc közepén keresztültörve tetejéről talapjáig, négymértföldnyi messzeségben;
kétoldalt hatszáz lábtól háromezerig emelkedő magas, egyenes sziklafalak, közepett az
óvilág óriás folyama, az Ister: a Duna. A ránehezülő víztömeg törte-e magának e kaput,
vagy a föld alatti tűz repeszté kétfelé a hegyláncot? Neptun alkotta-e ezt, vagy Volcán?
Vagy ketten együtt? A mű Istené! Ahhoz hasonlót még a mai istenutánzó kor vaskezű emberei
sem bírnak alkotni.

\index{együtt} \index{kétfelé}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't enable `-shell-escape` you get the warning

```
Package imakeidx Warning: Remember to run lualatex again after calling
(imakeidx)                `texindy -L hungarian -C utf8 magyaridx.idx'.
```

that tells you what to do.

Comment: an alternative to xindy would be upmendex which is more makeindex like and can handle unicode too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If only it had some documentation…

Comment: So I changed the order and the options accordingly, and it runs well, but unfortunately it's not in alphabetical order. Try adding `\index{kezdő}`

Comment: @egreg ask Frank ;-)

Comment: @Kazibácsi Complain with the Xindy developers.

Comment: Am I right then, that there's no point for me using `imakeidx` if it can't handle Hungarian accents?

Comment: @Kazibácsi `imakeidx` has little to do with the indexing programs: it just offers a friendlier interface and automatic calls to those programs. If the indexing program fails to provide correct sorting it's not a problem with `imakeidx`.

Comment: In the xindy manual they seem to have the correct alphabetical order for Hungarian...

Comment: @Kazibácsi What manual are you referring to? If it is `alphabet-doc`, then you should consider that it only deals with Latin-3.