# Random order of accented entries with texindy

Tags: indexing, accents, xindy, hungarian

After sorting out [my problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655624/135685) with `imakeidx`, I still have an issue with a wrong alphabetical order of accented Hungarian entries in the index. Updated MikTeX running `lualatex-dev.exe` with `-interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "%wm"` and `makeindex.exe` with `"%tm.idx" -t "%tm.ilg" -o "%tm.ind"`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-L hungarian -C utf8]

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing

Esztendők\index{óra} sora óta együtt\index{otthon} szoktam vacsorálni az István főherceg
vendéglőben az én igen t. barátommal, gróf\index{összes} Pongrácz Károly képviselővel és
tábornokkal. A hosszú téli estéken sokszor csak\index{enged} ketten ülünk a szokott
asztalnál, lenge\index{ősember} fátyol alatt, amely szivarjaink füstjéből szövődik, s ha
már kifogyott az aktuális beszélgetési anyag, szívesen\index{okozat} csúszunk kijjebb a
jelentől, az élményekben, színekben duzzadó múlt felé. Egymást ilyenkor szinte nem
is\index{éber} látjuk, hanem csak a múltat.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: Index]

I cannot fathom what *éber* is doing at *o* and why *összes* and *ősember* are separated. The correct order should be *éber, enged; okozat, óra, otthon; ősember, összes.* I've checked the [manual](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/make-rules-alphabets-doc.pdf) (p. 19), and the order seems to be fine there, but [I was told](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655624/imakeidx-fails-on-lualatex/655631?noredirect=1#comment1633842_655631) that the implementation is not in utf8.

Comment: You *don't* want to run `makeindex`, but rather `texindy`.

Comment: @egreg Non vedo nessun cambiamento, i risultati sono gli stessi con `texindy.exe`

Comment: you get the faulty order if you use makeindex. With texindy it is correct. Run `texindy -L hungarian -C utf8 your-file-name-here.idx` on a command line and check if it actually works and if it reports problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I got an error that Perl is not installed on my PC, trying now to fix that...

Answer (score 1):

If you run `lualatex-dev -shell-escape` on your document, you get (without running any auxiliary program)

[image]

Whether the collation order is good or not is a problem of Xindy.

I tried to convert the produced `.idx` file into Latin-2 and run `texindy` with the `-C latin2` option, and convert back the `.ind` file to UTF-8, but the result is exactly the same.

Note that `makeindex` will definitely go wrong.

Comment: Ok, it started to work, but strangely enough if I execute it from TeXnicCenter with the aforementioned settings, the .idx file is correctly produced, yet the .ind is an empty one. So I have to manually run texindy.exe with the same settings and I get the correct results. Do you have any ideas why it may happen?