# Index, Indic words, XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, indexing, indic

I am hoping to learn how to make an index that displays words sorted
in accordance with the Indic alphabet after having been input directly
in Unicode.

Comment: "Indic alphabet" is not very clear.  As such, it describes more a family of alphabets, used for different languages and with different scripts. Without specific information answers to this question can be only very general.

Answer (score 2):

You can automatically generate indices for any Unicode-encoded language with [xindy](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xindy). Note that xindy only works with TeX Live (not MiKTeX), and its documentation is poor.

Comment: Xindy works also with MiKTeX, please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex