# Xindy invisible to TeXStudio

Tags: glossaries, texstudio, xindy

I spent my morning trying to solve this problem and reading those previous questions

[How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex)

[makeglossaries call to xindy failed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153773/makeglossaries-call-to-xindy-failed)

[How to configure TexStudio editor to use Xindy?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118857/how-to-configure-texstudio-editor-to-use-xindy)

But the generation of my glossary with the `glossaries` package still fails.

I've figured out that if I open a terminal **from TeXStudio** it cannot find `xindy`

[image: xindy not recognized]

But if I manually open a Terminal I can manually compile my document :

[image]

And then I can run `pdflatex` again and the glossary works.

Here are my options inside TeXStudio :

Meta-compilations:
[image]

Compilations:
[image]

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}


\begin{document}

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

**P.S.** : I've uninstalled and reinstalled Perl, MikTeX as well as TeXStudio just to make sure that it wasn't a version issue.

I realize this problem is very similar to the questions posted above but I don't know what I can do at this point.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you give the absolute path to xindy in the texstudio preferences?

Comment: @samcarter I'm not sure what you mean, Isn't that what I did with the line `"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/texindy.exe" %.idx` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure  `Makeglossaries`  as follows:
[image]

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: It worked but I still had to add `C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` to the `$PATH` as shown in my answer. 
At least we know what's wrong. I'm marking your answer as the answer to my question.

Comment: I don't think installing perl  is necessary (I don't have it): MiKTeX has its own `runperl.exe`. As to the path to the bin directory of MiKTeX, I don't understand why you had to add it to your path: it is automatically added at installation.

Comment: I don't understand it either and a neat explanation would be welcome but right now if it works it's all that matters to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I added `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` to the `$PATH` as well as the Perl directory and now it works. It seems like a dirty solution but at least it works! I'll wait a little while before marking this answer as the answer for this problem just in case someone finds something cleaner.

[image]