# Index in Swedish sorting order ( ...YZÅÄÖ...) with xindy and LaTeX

Tags: indexing, sorting

I still haven't succeed to sort Swedish letters in the index list with class `article` in the correct order.

I've tried it with specifying a sort key, i.e. `\index{g~ra@göra}`, but the result is not perfect. There will not be any empty lines between the groups of Å, Ä, and Ö sorting. And the extra coding job seems not be up to date 2014.

This way is quite cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Xindy should do the work (easy?), but how do I setup xindy to create an index with Swedish sorting order?

My comment:  All texts are not written in English. I like the LaTeX system, it's a lot better than Word in my case, but the sorting troubles me.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that with `inputenc` and `utf8` option, index files are written in a way that `xindy` cannot process. This sample:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
This kind of index in text:

\index{Säker plats|textbf}Säker plats
foo\index{Aäö}\index{Aäö}
bar\index{äö}\index{aø}\index{ohne}\index{øæ}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

produces this `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{S\IeC {\"a}ker plats|textbf}{1}
\indexentry{A\IeC {\"a}\IeC {\"o}}{1}
\indexentry{A\IeC {\"a}\IeC {\"o}}{1}
\indexentry{\IeC {\"a}\IeC {\"o}}{1}
\indexentry{a\IeC {\o }}{1}
\indexentry{ohne}{1}
\indexentry{\IeC {\o }\IeC {\ae }}{1}
```

you need to convert this code to `utf8`. It is possible to do this using my script [iec2utf](https://github.com/michal-h21/iec2utf). Download the file `iec2utf.lua` to the directory with your document and make batch script `swedxindy`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
texlua iec2utf.lua T1 < `basename $1 .tex`.idx | texindy -i -M lang/swedish/utf8-lang -o `basename $1 .tex`.ind
```

I don't use `texshop` so I don't know how to add this script to the menu, but you can call it from command line (you will have to make it executable, I think it can be made with command `chmod -x swedxindy` like in Linux).

**Edit**

I simplified the process - there is now script called `utftexindy` in the `iec2utf` repository. Process described above can be now simplified to:

```
texlua utftexindy.lua -L swedish sample.idx
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This should definitely go to CTAN.

Comment: @egreg I have quite a long list of packages which I want to post to CTAN, but I am really struggling with documentation. But I plan to do it :)

Comment: This really ought to be fixed at `xindy` level given that so many LaTeX users use it.

Comment: Michal: Typo on your github resource, an f is missing (must be `@echo off`). But the real problem is: no `ieclib` existant here (Win7-64).

Comment: @Speravir `ieclib` is included in `iec2utf` respository. I updated documentation, I hope it is more clear now :)

Comment: Aargh, how could I overlook this … But it runs now fine here! And the batch file is not needed anymore *<g>*. BTW I’m a MiKTeX user with this adjustment: [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71167/9237).

Answer (score 8):

In his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153903/16967) michal.h21 has identified the problem and found the problem in the way, UTF-8 characters are written, if `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is used:

```
\IeC{<LICR>}% LICR = LaTeX Internal Character Representation
```

Since package `inputenc` makes the 8-bit bytes active, they can be redefined to print themselves instead of the `\IeC` stuff.

Also `\index` uses verbatim category codes for its argument. LaTeX does not include 8-bit characters in its verbatim category codes, because it has to map the UTF-8 byte sequence to a character slot of a font encoding to get the correct character.

The following example, based on michal.h21's example, patches `\index` that it does not write expanded UTF-8 characters:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\index{\@sanitize}{\@sanitize\index@sanitize}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \noexpand\index failed}%
}
\let\index@sanitize\@empty
\begingroup
  \count@=127
  \@whilenum\count@<255 \do{%
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \lccode`\*=\count@
    \lccode`\~=\count@
    \lowercase{%
      \expandafter
      \g@addto@macro\expandafter\index@sanitize\expandafter{%
        % verbatim catcode
        \expandafter\@makeother\csname *\endcsname
        % active character expands to non-expandable itself
        \def~{*}%
      }%

    }%  
  }
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This kind of index in text:

\index{Säker plats|textbf}Säker plats
foo\index{Aäö}\index{Aäö}
bar\index{äö}\index{aø}\index{ohne}\index{øæ}

\textbf{foo\index{Aäö}\index{Aäö}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The following `.idx` file is written:

```
\indexentry{Säker plats|textbf}{1}
\indexentry{Aäö}{1}
\indexentry{Aäö}{1}
\indexentry{äö}{1}
\indexentry{aø}{1}
\indexentry{ohne}{1}
\indexentry{øæ}{1}
\indexentry{Aäö}{1}
\indexentry{Aäö}{1}
```

Comment: Nice, perhaps this ought to be made into a package

Comment: @daleif: I am thinking about making a package. But I haven't a name yet. Something with UTF-8 is too special, because this method can be used with other encodings as well. Perhaps something like "inputencsanitize".

Comment: Should it only hit `\index`?

Comment: @daleif: `\index` is indeed a prominent application, but there are others, try `\typeout`, for example. It is useful for any application that writes to a file or console.

Comment: Hmm, it does not work with `memoir` because the patching fails.

Comment: because the `\@sanitize` is in a different macro in `mmeoir` (`\@index` ion order to be able to specify multiple index files)

Comment: @daleif: A very first pre-alpha version: [iecsan.pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71873949/tmp/iecsan.pdf). (PDF file contains `iecsan.dtx` as file attachment. Run it through plain TeX to get the package file.) I have to stop now and continue later with the hard part (package compatibility; perhaps I will add an package option `index=(true|false)` → `\usepackage[index]{iecsan}`); documentation; ...).

Comment: Will have a look, BTW: it seems you are loading `etoolbox` twice.

Comment: @daleif: Macro `\iecsan` is implemented, the remaining part of patching index macros will be rewritten anyway.

Comment: No problem. The code works fine.

Comment: Great work. From first tests, it looks like the pacakge has no effect on when using the indexing option of `biblatex` (which probably uses its own indexing routines. Any plans for that?

Comment: The package doesn't seem to be part of the oberdiek bundle. `biblatex` still does not "listen" to this patch.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative (requires at least version 4.02 of [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries)):

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[index,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newterm[name={Säker plats}]{Saker plats}
\newterm[name={Aäö}]{Aao}
\newterm[name={äö}]{ao}
\newterm[name={aø}]{aoslash}
\newterm{ohne}
\newterm[name={øæ}]{oae}

\begin{document}
This kind of index in text:

\gls[format=textbf]{Saker plats}
foo\glsadd{Aao}\glsadd{Aao}
bar\glsadd{ao}\glsadd{aoslash}\glsadd{ohne}\glsadd{oae}

\printindex[style=indexgroup]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

This works because the default behaviour of `glossaries` is to sanitize the sort key before writing it to the external indexing file, so the `.idx` file for the above looks like:

```
(indexentry :tkey (("Säker plats" "\\glossentry{Saker plats}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pagetextbf" )
(indexentry :tkey (("Aäö" "\\glossentry{Aao}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
(indexentry :tkey (("Aäö" "\\glossentry{Aao}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
(indexentry :tkey (("äö" "\\glossentry{ao}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
(indexentry :tkey (("aø" "\\glossentry{aoslash}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
(indexentry :tkey (("ohne" "\\glossentry{ohne}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
(indexentry :tkey (("øæ" "\\glossentry{oae}") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
```

so xindy is able to sort the entries correctly.

The drawback is that each indexed entry must be first defined using `\newterm` and the label can't contain unicode characters such as ø. (This is because the label forms the names of control sequences that store the entry's information.)