# index (xindy): How does one customize alphabetical order?

Tags: languages, sorting, xindy, dictionaries

I'm trying to index all the words from my old [conlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language), whose alphabetical order goes `aæbcçdðefghijklɬłnñŋməoœœ̄pqrsßtťþuůvwxyz` instead of the regular `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` we're all familiar with.

There are also secondary rules for diacritics that only kick in when two words are identical except for the accents; I'll include them below.

- I can't find anything that lets me redefine the alphabetical order so
  that I can automatically sort all the vocab entries the way I need
  to.
- Theoretically, I could make a sorting algorithm with `xstring`
  but I *really* don't want to because the sheer amount of work
  involved sounds extremely unpleasant, and it would take an
  obnoxiously long time to compile.
- I've tried using `xindy` as well but it's not cooperating at all and at this point using it feels like significantly more trouble than it's worth.
- I'm on overleaf if that helps at all.
- I don't have any working code for entries; I've been
  using just a stylistic command `\entry` (source below).

Rules for diacritics: when two words have identical spelling except for diacritics (e.g. chazín and ĉhazín), the word without the diacritic goes first, and then the diacritics will go in the following order: `a, à, á, â, ǎ, ä, ã, å, ȧ, ă`. (Note to anyone who also does this stuff: yes, I'm fully aware that this is not a great way to go about things.)

`\entry` code: `\newcommand\entry[6]{\textbf{#1}\defsep\textit{#2}\defsep[#3]\defsep#4\defsep#5\defsep#6\par}` with `\defsep` being `\newcommand\defsep{\hspace{0.05in}$\cdot$\hspace{0.05in}}`

Edit: Ok so I wholly and totally forgot to add an MWE; sorry about that. I'm not sure if this is exactly what I'm supposed to do for these but here goes. Ideally what I'd be able to do is something like

```
\entry{word=idyr,tr=between,IPA=idɪɾ,etym=from Irish *idir*,pos=prep}
\entry{word=ðormaï,tr=bedroom,IPA=d̪ð͡oɾma.i,etym=from Spanish *dormitorio*,pos=noun}
\entry{word=ŷ,tr=to be,IPA=aj,etym=from Spanish *hay*,pos=verb,irr=infinitive is ŷ instead of ŷín}
\entry{word=ə́lunfr̂at,tr=alliance,IPA=ˈəlunfʀat,etym=unknown,pos=noun,irr=none}
\entry{word=ĉhazin,tr=to do,IPA=xazˈin,etym=ultimately from Portuguese *fazer*,pos=v,irr=none}
```

and have it spit out the entries formatted and in the right order, which would look something like

---

ĉhazin *v.* (pr. [xazˈin]) **to do**, ultimately from Portuguese *fazer*. Regular conjugation.

ðormaï *n.* (pr. [d̪͡ðoɾma.i]) **bedroom**, from Spanish *dormitorio*.

idyr *prep.* (pr. [idɪɾ]) **between**, from Irish *idir*.

ə́lunfr̂at *n.* (pr. [ˈəlunfʀat]) **alliance**, unnknown etymology.

ŷ *v.* (pr. [aj]) **to be**, from Spanish *hay*. Infinitive is ŷ instead of ŷín.

---

I can handle the formatting fine; it's just the sorting itself I need help with. Thanks again!

Comment: Is a LuaTeX solution acceptable?

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Overleaf has support for LuaLaTex; idk how different that is but yes I can use it

Comment: It's best if you add a so-called "MWE", see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. This helps others and yourself.

Comment: Is this helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153858

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Ok I added the MWE (or my best attempt at it); hope that helps. And the link wasn't particularly helpful just because it seemed to rely mostly on babel and the fact that Swedish is already incorporated in it, which doesn't really help me. If I'm just being dense pls let me know, and thanks for your help :)

Comment: The MWE should be **compilable** (self contained but yet minimal) as described in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228

Comment: @generallyconfuzzled https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/672292 (you might want to keep a track of this question).