# Error compiling with Xindy?

Tags: compiling, xindy

I try compiling Xindy document at LaTeX and my MWE like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
    
\newglossaryentry{gloss}{
    name=glossaries,
    description=A package for generating glossaries in many styles
    }
    
\begin{document}
    
\texttt{\gls{gloss}} is a great package!
    
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I follow instruction installing Xindy from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex/71168#71168) and I try to compile it with

```
xindy -L english -I xindy -M "testfile" -t "testfile.glg" -o "testfile.gls" "testfile.glo"
```

And I get error like this :

[image: ioy]
What is **ScriptPath** from  this script path ?

```
@echo off
set ScriptPath=<localtexmf>\scripts\xindy
perl %ScriptPath%\texindy.pl %*
```

I feel *error* from script above it .

Comment: What exactly is this installation? Is xindy installed by hand?

Comment: The xindy.pl has changed and some of the steps mentioned in the question you linked too are imho no longer up-to-date. See this feature request for more informations (and read the comments!) https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/feature-requests/319/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank for your comment , but what is the implementation xindy ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , How to make a wrapper xindy.exe and texindy.exe? What do you mean ScriptPath from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex ?

Comment: @Hirwanto: Rereading the answer of speravir more carefully I see that he has updated it in 2014 so probably it will work with a newer xindy.pl. But I don't have the time to test. Try if it works if Scriptpath points to the *absolute* path of the local tree where you put the xindy files.