# MiKTeX and Xindy problems

Tags: miktex, glossaries, xindy

Today's updates of MiKTeX include Xindy (at last!). This is great news, but unfortunately I can't get it to work. With the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\newacronym{AKA}{AKA}{Also Known As}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

`makeglossaries` fails with exit code 25. This is the contents of the `.glg` file:

```
;; This logfile was generated automatically by `xindy'
;; at 20.06.2015  07:29:59
;; Indexstyle: "5i3SDna0ed", Rawindex: "Yl65BHMXsP", Output: "test1.gls"

ERROR: "" is not a valid filename !

*** Unable to execute: '"xindy"  -L english  -I xindy -M "test1" -t "test1.glg" -o "test1.gls" "test1.glo"' ***

Failed with error code 1.

Status report:

Opening logfile "test1.glg" (done)
Reading indexstyle...
Loading module "5i3SDna0ed"...

Error in line 1:
(require "")
ERROR: "" is not a valid filename !
```

and this is the contents of the generated `5i3SDna0ed` file

```
(require "")
(require "test1.xdy")
```

Do I need to configure something to get Xindy to work?

Comment: You might want to add the glossaries tag as well. Then perhaps Nicola will notice the issue (Nicola is the writer of the glossaries package). She is on the site.

Comment: Also it is a strange error. I don't see anything wrong with the line it is attempting to execute

Comment: In my case, line 1 of test1.xdy is `(require "tex.xdy")`.
I think `(require "")` is strange.

Comment: I would like to look at it, but I don't have the update yet and the repositories are down currently so I can't get it. So it will have to wait ...

Comment: This works fine for me with `makeglossaries` version 2.15, `glossaries.sty` version 4.15 and `xindy` version 2.5.0. Can you directly run the command it's trying to execute?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Same error: `Error in line 1: (require "") ERROR: "" is not a valid filename !`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Have you been able to install the update?

Comment: The repositories are still offline, but I installed the miktex xindy from CTAN and a local repository. Your example compiled without error. Do you have a 32bit like me or a 64bit? What is your perl version?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 32-bit MiKTeX and Strawberry Perl 5.18

Comment: Since line 1 of your `test1.xdy` file is a comment, I don't think the error refers to that file. The error message comes after `Loading module "5i3SDna0ed"...` so I think the error is in that file, but that's a temporary file created by `xindy` and is deleted at the end of the `xindy` run. I think the problem may be with your particular version of `xindy`. It might be worth contacting the xindy mailing list.

Comment: A command
`xindy -d keep_tmpfiles -L english -I xindy -M test1 -t test1.glg -o test1.gls test1.glo`
leaves temporary files, probably in the current working
directory in the case of Windows.

Comment: The contents of a temporary file in my case were
`(require "lang/english/latin9-lang.xdy")`
`(require "test1.xdy")`

Comment: @AkiraKakuto thanks for the info. In my case the temp file contains `(require "")`

Comment: I can only imagine that it is a perl problem. I have active perl, version 5.16.3. and it works fine, there is no require with empty argument. The code for the temporary style file is in xindy.pl around line 800.

Comment: @Sterry : By adding `-d script` option, you obtain more information
on your screen:
`xindy -d script -d keep_tmpfiles -L english -I xindy -M test1 -t test1.glg -o test1.gls test1.glo`
Please try.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Tried with latest version of ActivePerl and Strawberry Perl, but same error :-(

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I bet that the error comes from the fact I installed MiKTeX in a directory containing spaces.

Comment: @Sterry: This is certainly a difference to my system, but I don't know this would lead to a missing `lang/english/latin9-lang.xdy` in the style. Did you check if there are updates? Did you try to deinstall and reinstall xindy?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer See the answer below. Do you mind to send a bug report to  Christian Schenk?

Comment: Yes, I do mind. It is you who found the bug, so you can handle it. Beside this: the line is also in the xindy.pl of texlive, so imho you should better contact Joachim Schrod.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks a lot. I have updated xindy.pl in TeX Live: r37650.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry if I asked. I sent a mail to J. Schrod.

Comment: @Sterry: As Akira updated the sources it is probably no longer necessary. I will add a message in miktex bug tracker that it is necessary to sync.

Comment: The bug should be resolved now see https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2372/. But looking at the next question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252299/xindy-and-miktex-empty-raw-index-file) I bet more "path-with-spaces-errors" will emerge ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is indeed related to a MiKTeX installation in a path containing spaces. It can be solved by a small edit in **C:\Program Files\MiKTeX2.9\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl**

replace in line 779

```
        @styles = glob("$lang_dir/$variant$cp*-lang.xdy");
```

by

```
        @styles = glob("'$lang_dir/$variant$cp*-lang.xdy'");
```

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Joachim says that the solution may break xindy on Unix.
Thus we have changed slightly in TeX Live (r37716).
The new one is tested to work fine on Windows in the
case where `$lang_dir` contains space(s).