# Xindy and MiKTeX: empty raw index file

Tags: miktex, xindy

I try to use xindy in MiKTeX. When I compile

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
test\index{test}\index{text}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

with

```
latex test.tex
texindy test.idx
```

it prints

```
C:/Program is not an internal command, external command, program or batch file.
Opening logfile "nul" (done)
Reading indexstyle...
Loading module "r0Ri4_6RwG"...
Loading module "lang/general/latin9-lang.xdy"...
Loading module "lang/general/latin9.xdy"...
Finished loading module "lang/general/latin9.xdy".
Finished loading module "lang/general/latin9-lang.xdy".
Loading module "tex/inputenc/latin.xdy"...
Finished loading module "tex/inputenc/latin.xdy".
Loading module "texindy.xdy"...
Loading module "numeric-sort.xdy"...
Finished loading module "numeric-sort.xdy".
Loading module "latex.xdy"...
Loading module "tex.xdy"...
Finished loading module "tex.xdy".
Finished loading module "latex.xdy".
Loading module "latex-loc-fmts.xdy"...
Finished loading module "latex-loc-fmts.xdy".
Loading module "makeindex.xdy"...
Finished loading module "makeindex.xdy".
Loading module "latin-lettergroups.xdy"...
Finished loading module "latin-lettergroups.xdy".
Finished loading module "texindy.xdy".
Loading module "page-ranges.xdy"...
Finished loading module "page-ranges.xdy".
Loading module "word-order.xdy"...
Finished loading module "word-order.xdy".
Finished loading module "r0Ri4_6RwG".
Finished reading indexstyle.
Finalizing indexstyle... (done)

Reading raw-index "zBpYoFHjX4"...
Finished reading raw-index.

Processing index... [10%] [20%] [30%] [40%] [50%] [60%] [70%] [80%] [90%] [100%]

Finished processing index.

Writing markup... [10%] [20%] [30%] [40%] [50%] [60%] [70%] [80%] [90%] [100%]
Markup written into file "test.ind".
```

The problem is that text.ind contains an empty theindex environment.  Also, with the option `-d kepp_tmpfiles` I can see that the raw-index file is empty (the file `zBpYoFHjX4`above).

Note, the error/warning message `C:/Program is not an internal command, ...` from texindy.

I don't know if the following is related. If I try to compile xindy in Cygwin I get the error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\xindy\texindy.pl: not a symlink as required for
TeX Live at C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\xindy\texindy.pl  line 423.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Seems a problem with the spaces in your installation directory. Can you run xindy? (See eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251221/miktex-and-xindy-problems? for examples). Then you could avoid texindy.

Comment: That's also a very strange error message. Why is it mentioning TeX Live when this a MikTeX installation?

Comment: @daleif: It is quite possible that texindy.pl hasn't all the correct tests for miktex, or that is a cygwin problem.  Imho texindy isn't really needed. You can always use a xindy -M texindy instead.

Comment: Just gets complicated for the user

Comment: @daleif Imho with utf8 you need it anyway.

Comment: isn't that because there is missing development on `xindy`?

Comment: `xindy -M texindy` produces also an empty raw index file in WIndows  command line (cmd) and the following error in Cygwin: `/cygdrive/c/Users/Robert/Documents/tmp/xindy/minimal/C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/xindy/../../xindy/modules: No such file or directory at C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 402`

Comment: Did you check for updates? One bug regarding spaces in the installation directory was corrected yesterday.  (I have no idea regarding the cygwin error, I doubt that is a good idea to try ro run miktex in it).

Comment: I think that it is the best to reinstall MikTeX in a
directory without spaces. xindy seems not to support
paths with spaces.
It is quite possible that there are other programs
than xindy which do not fully support paths with spaces.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I have further updated texindy.pl and xindy.pl
in the TeX Live in order to support spaces in paths (r37686).
I hope that `texindy ...`  and `xindy -M texindy ...` work
in the case of Robert after a sync.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: It was not necessary to change texindy.pl.
See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It was not necessary to change texindy.pl.
Please add a line

```
$filter=quotify($filter);
```

at the next line of line 719 of xindy.pl.
After the change,
sub filter_index becomes as follows:

```
sub filter_index ( $$ ) {
    my ($filter, $input) = @_;
    my $output = tmpnam();
    push (@temp_files, $output);
    $output=quotify($output);
    $filter=quotify($filter);
    print "Running filter: $filter <$input >$output\n"  if $verbose;
    system "$filter <$input >$output";
    print "filtered xindy input file: $output\n"  if $debug{script};
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: That solved the error message `C:/Program is not an internal command ...`. It turns out that xindy couldn't run tex2xindy, which I think explain the empty raw index file. Still xindy couldn't find tex2xindy, since it searches in `<path to MiKTeX>/xindy/../../miktex/bin/internal/`. It works if I copy `tex2xindy.exe`to `/miktex/bin/internal/`.Thank you for the help!

Comment: `tex2xindy.exe` is used only by xindy and it should
be in
`.../miktex/bin/internal`
in the case of 32bit MikTeX
or in
`.../miktex/bin/x64/internal`
in the case of 64bit MikTeX.
Please tell the MikTeX developer.