# Call to xindy failed due to double path on windows

Tags: miktex, glossaries, windows, xindy

I have a problem with makeglossaries after installing MikTex on my windows10 machine. pdflatex and biber work perfectly fine, yet when calling `makeglossaries` it fails with the following error message:

```
$makeglossaries Main
makeglossaries version 4.36 (2018-03-07)
added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)
xindy  -L english -C duden-utf8 -I xindy -M "Main" -t "Main.glg" -o "Main.gls" "                                                                       Main.glo"
/d/local/thesis/C:/Program Files/MiKTeX2.9/scripts/xindy/../../xindy                                                                       /modules: No such file or directory at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX2.9\scripts\xindy\                                                                       xindy.pl line 402.

***Call to xindy failed***

Check 'Main.glg' for details
```

I checked out [wolfie's Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251221/miktex-and-xindy-problems/251801#251801) but find that this was already implemented in the xindy script.

The error seems to be that the path is concatenated in the `$real_cmd` variable in the script on line 372.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is a striped down version of my latex setup:

Main.tex:

```
\documentclass[
 11pt,              
   english,
   a4paper,           
   DIV=11,            
   listof=numbered,
]{scrreprt}

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parskip}{0.75em}   
\usepackage{geometry}          
\geometry{bindingoffset=0.5cm,hmarginratio=3:4, bottom=4.5cm}

\widowpenalty10000          
\clubpenalty10000

%---- PACKAGES ----
%\usepackage{hyperref}      
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{textcomp}       
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage{pdfpages}       
\pdfminorversion=7          
\usepackage{graphicx}       

\usepackage{tabularx}      
\usepackage{hhline}         
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1} 
\makeatletter               
\newcommand{\thickhline}{
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\makeatother

\def\hyph{-\penalty0\hskip0pt\relax}    

\usepackage{xcolor}     

\definecolor{bostonuniversityred}{rgb}{0.8, 0.0, 0.0}

% This is the interesting part I guess -------------------------------
\usepackage[section=section,numberedsection=autolabel,toc,nonumberlist,xindy]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}
\makeglossaries     
\input{glossary.tex}    
% ----------------------------------------------------------------- 

\usepackage[chapter]{minted}        
\usepackage{scrhack} 
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Code Snippets}
\renewcommand{\listoflistingscaption}{List of Code Snippet}


\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}        
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

%---- BIBLIOGRAPHY ---
\usepackage[block=ragged,backend=biber,bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}     
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@maxline{77}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

         \gls{someEntry} 
         \gls{someEntry2} 

    \newpage
    \printglossary[title=Glossary]
\end{document}
```

glossary.tex:

```
\newglossaryentry{someEntry}{
    name={Some Entry},
    description={Some Description}
}
\newglossaryentry{someEntry2}{
    name={Some Entry 2},
    description={Some Description 2}
}
```

In the resulting pdf File the name is visible, so it read the glossary file correctly, but was not able to print it due to the makeglossaries command failing.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add some working code?

Comment: Hi, and thanks. Do you mean a examplenary template? I could add that.

Comment: As a temporary solution try `makeglossaries -x "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX2.9/scripts/xindy" Main` (replace `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX2.9/scripts/xindy` with the appropriate path)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot This does not seem to work, but I might missunderstood you. the path should be pointing to the xindy.pl file right? If I add the file to the path, then I get an error due to some linking issue, and if I remove the specific filename and leave the path to the directroy, it fails due to the path beeing a directory.

Comment: What happens if you rename your main file?

Comment: What happens if you try `makeglossaries-lite Main` instead?

Comment: Makeglossaries Version 4.36 (2018-03-07)

Comment: `makeglossaries-lite` is not recognized..

Comment: @CyrillC It might be called `makeglossaries-lite.lua`. It should be located in the same directory as `makeglossaries.exe`. Alternatively you can fetch it from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries).

Comment: What do you get if you do `makeglossaries -n Main`?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Neither works, the output of `makeglossaries -n Main` is

`makeglossaries version 4.36 (2018-03-07)`
`added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)`
`xindy  -L english -C duden-utf8 -I xindy -M "Main" -t` `"Main.glg" -o "Main.gls" "Main.glo"`

Comment: I will have a look a gendoftest's answer, yet I believe you are more capable of deciding if this would be something to implement =)

Comment: @CyrillC The `-n` switch just displays the version and shows how it would invoke `xindy`/`makeindex` without actually doing anything. I just wanted to check if there was a problem with the way that `makeglossaries` is invoking `xindy`. From your comment it seems to be invoking `xindy` correctly, in which case the problem is with `xindy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I digged a bit deeper and found a partial solution. Since I don't have enough karma yet, I cannot post this as comments though (and I am not sure it would be the right way).

xindy.pl line 372 reads:

```
our $real_cmd = Cwd::realpath($0);
```

If I add

```
print "real_cmd: $real_cmd\n";
```

after that, it prints

```
real_cmd: /c/Users/username/Desktop/TeX/auxdir/C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/xindy/xindy.pl
```

which is wrong.

Putting these lines into a test file named `test_Cwd.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Cwd;
our $real_cmd = Cwd::realpath($0);
print "real_cmd: $real_cmd\n";
```

Output with windows paths:

```
$ C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test_Cwd.pl
real_cmd: /c/Users/username/Desktop/C:/Users/username/Desktop/test_Cwd.pl
```

Output with emulated unix paths on Windows:

```
$ /c/Users/username/Desktop/test_Cwd.pl
real_cmd: /c/Users/username/Desktop/test_Cwd.pl
```

This difference in behavior of perl is know and described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773471.

Possible solutions:

1. Fix `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\xindy.exe` to execute perl with `/c/Program\ Files/MiKTeX\ 2.9/scripts/xindy/xindy.pl` on msys. I don't know how to do this as I am unable to find the package providing xindy.exe.
2. Fix `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/xindy/xindy.pl` to convert the Windows-style path to a Unix-style path (dirty hack, done below)
3. Fix the perl interpreter's `Cwd` package to convert Windows-style paths to Unix-style paths (general solution, may break other code)

Msys and Cygwin also have the `cygpath` utility which does help creating a workaround:

You'll need to fix platform detection in `xindy.pl` first, see https://sourceforge.net/p/xindy/feature-requests/47/.

Then replace `xindy.pl` line 372, which looks like this

```
our $real_cmd = Cwd::realpath($0);
```

by

```
our $real_cmd = "";
if ( $is_w32 ) {
    our $cygpath_cmdline = "cygpath \"$0\"";
    our $unixified_cmd_path = `$cygpath_cmdline`;
    $unixified_cmd_path =~ s/\r//g;
    $unixified_cmd_path =~ s/\n//g;
    our $real_cmd = Cwd::realpath($unixified_cmd_path);
} else {
    our $real_cmd = Cwd::realpath($0);
}
```

But then xindy-lisp.exe will fail reading the tempdir filename:

```
*** - PARSE-NAMESTRING: syntax error in filename
  "\"/c/Users/username/Desktop/TeX/auxdir/FVWzOBrFBF\"" at position 0
```

This file does exist, but xindy-lisp.exe seems to expect the filename without `\"` but with *single double quotes* instead. Manually editing the commandline and removing `\"` gets me further. When parsing the temporary file and reading other paths from there, it fails again.

I am using perl from git-bash (msys, 64Bit) with MiKTeX 64Bit on Windows 7. All software is updated to its latest version afaik, except maybe perl.

```
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64- 
msys-thread-multi
```

PS: my perl code may be bad style as I am new to perl. Suggestions are welcome!