# Which Perl to install for Xindy with MiKTeX (on Windows)?

Tags: miktex, xindy, perl

**Please, read the question before marking it as duplicate.**

Since June 2015, `xindy` is finally included in the MiKTeX distribution for Windows. Unfortunately, this does not mean that you can use `xindy` out of the box. At least on my system, I still get the error message:

```
xindy: The Perl interpreter could not be found
```

So, hopefully, the only missing thing is a Perl interpreter to run `xindy`. I searched the MiKTeX documentation and also the Web, but I did not found an answer to my question, which Perl interpreter to install for Windows. There are three different interpreters to choose from at https://www.perl.org/get.html

Could somebody, please, give a new answer to that question instead of just linking to [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex) which is usally done. This link does not answer my question.

To nail done my prerequisites:

- I don't care about doing anything (else) with Perl. I just want `xindy` to work.
- I would prefer a Perl distribution which is easy to install (if there is a difference between the distributions).

If installing Perl distribution XY is not enough to get `xindy` work, it would be nice to know.

Comment: For general preference I'd go with Strawberry, but will have to test it works OK with `xindy`/MiKTeX.

Comment: There are at least two easy-to-install Perl distributions for Win32, I am aware of.  You could use the [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) environment, which provides many GNU/Linux tools for native use.  The other choice is [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads).

Comment: @HenriMenke I would like to avoid Cygwin, if possible.

Comment: Strawberry is a good choice as Joseph mentioned also and very easy to install.

Comment: Strawberry is nice, and updates and installs new packages nicely. Side comment: I wonder if the 'xindy' folks could make a standalone Windows executable version

Comment: @JosephWright I followed the majority of the commentators and installed Strawberry just now. Installation was easy (as promised) with a small tripping hazard - the path name should not contain a space in it. The installer reveals that AFTER installation. Lucky me, I did not use one. Now, `xindy` talks to me :-) Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most straight-forward to use Perl system on Windows is [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/). It sticks closely to the way Perl works across other platforms, so whilst it is not 'adapted' for Windows that's probably a good thing. The only point to notice is that you should not install with a path with spaces in it: I'd go with `C:\strawberry`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the installation path, I used `c:\ProgrammeNoAdmin\Strawberry` which also worked. I put all stuff that is critical with spaces or admin rights into `c:\ProgrammeNoAdmin` to keep my root directory clean.