# How to tell texindy where to look for the script engine?

Tags: installing, windows, texworks, xindy, perl

I decided to start using `xindy`. I'm using MikTex on a Windows machine so I realized I need to install Perl manually, because when running `texindy` (in TeXworks) it says:

```
texindy.exe: The script engine could not be found.
texindy.exe: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"
```

So I read [Which Perl to install for Xindy with MiKTeX (on Windows)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256096) and installed Strawberry Perl. I get the same message, so I'm thinking I should tell `texindy` where Perl is installed. Am I right? How do I do this?

Comment: or just install texlive instead of miktex , on windows TL  brings its own perl so texindy works out of the box

Comment: What happens if you call in a command line or in a powershell window `perl --version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message disappeared as follows: I ran `texindy` from a command line instead of via TeXworks. By doing so MikTeX realized that the script `xindy.pl` (or was it `texindy.pl`? I don't remember) was missing, and it installed it.

For the record: After that the message changed to

```
xindy.pl: input file <filename> does not exist at <path>/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/xindy/xindy.pl line 549.
```

but I assume that's another story.