# How to use Miktex's Xindy package?

Tags: miktex, xindy

Using the package manager one can install a package titled `tex2xindy binaries`. However, the executable `tex2xindy.exe` is installed to `miktex\bin\x64\internal\` and is thus not added to the system path. When trying to execute it explicitly, the program crashes (procedure entry point "" not found). How is `tex2xindy` for Miktex supposed to work?

Comment: Usually it is not needed to execute `tex2xindy` as a
user command. It is a filter used internally.
User commands are `xindy` and `texindy`.

Comment: The only file which matches `*indy*.exe` contained in the Miktex installation folder is `tex2xindy.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex), xindy has been included with MikTeX since June 2015. As long as `MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` is included in your path, you'll have `xindy` and `texindy` available. Here's a MWE:

xindy-test.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx,lipsum}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\index{Hello}
\index{world}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

You build with, e.g.:

```
xelatex xindy-test
texindy -C utf8 -L english -o xindy-test.ind xindy-test.idx
xelatex xindy-test
```