# How to install MathTime Pro 2 fonts on MikTeX

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex, texmf, mtpro

I have been trying for a long time now to install the [MathTime Professional II (mtpro2)](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) fonts on my system. (I am running MikTeX 2.9 under Windows 7, but what likely matters is "recent MikTeX, under Windows", which is general enough to be of interest to many people.) I've tried various things:

1. First step:

   - Merging the "texmf" directory structure into my MikTeX root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9") *or*
   - registering a new root directory ("C:\Local TeX Files") and

     - putting `mtpro2`'s "texmf" directory directly in there *or*
     - putting the subdirectories of `mtpro2`'s "texmf" directory in there
2. Second step: Running `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` and adding the lines "# MathTimePro II" and "Map mtpro2.map" to the file.
3. Third step: Running any and all of the following commands in various orders and combinations:

   - From the command prompt (always in Administrator mode (right-click -> "Run as administrator")): `updmap`, `texhash`, `mktexlsr`, `initexmf --admin -u`
   - Accessing the MikTeX "Options" dialogue (via running MikTeX 2.9 -> Settings as Administrator) and then choosing both "Refresh FNDB" and "Update Formats"

None of this seems to work. Right now the error messages I get when trying to compile the enclosed sample file "MTPro2 LaTeX test.tex" is the following:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file mt2exf): Font mt2exf at 2400 not found
>
> ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I have no clue what's happening. Also I hope I haven't cluttered the hash/database files with incorrect information in this process.

How do I install the MathTime Professional II fonts under MikTeX?

Comment: See also [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) (with links to [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) and [Purpose of local texmf trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/purpose-of-local-texmf-trees)).

Comment: I installed the font package and the test compiled fine. After looking again onto your question I must say it seems here, too, that you mixed up something: [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex). Run again _without_ `--admin` (!): `initexmf --force -u` and then `updmap --force`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** See now the more general tutorial [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

---

I did the following and it worked for me. Some steps may not be necessary or have been done redundantly. I believe I did everything in "user" mode.

1. Created `C:\Local TeX Files`
2. Put zipped fonts distribution in temporary directory and unzipped there
3. `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` opened there `mo.exe`. changed default format to letter and added to roots C:\Local TeX Files. needed to do show  MiKTeX maintained root directories so it is in the right priority among directories. System said it needed to rebuild format files and did so.
4. Move the contents of the `texmf` folder to your own root directory (`C:\Local TeX Files`)
5. From a command line run

   ```
   initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
   ```
6. Empty file opened in notepad
7. Add the following two lines to the file

   - `# MathTimePro II`
   - `Map mtpro2.map`
8. Save and exit
9. Do not change cmd directory. From a command line run (this took a long time)

   ```
   updmap
   ```
10. refresh FNDB (user). update formats
11. do the following two commands on two different lines from command line

    - `initexmf --mkmaps`
    - `updmap`
12. refresh FNDB (user). update formats

Comment: I followed your instructions (with minor differences in path names on my computer/setup), and things worked! Good job. For me, I'm sure that I had previously done basically all of these (as user or admin) except the line `initexmf --mkmaps`.

Comment: When I try to run `updmap` command in the command line Windows says:  
Sorry, but mkfntmap did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/OPTICAMADO/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/updmap.log
You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I've found is that the installation puts updmap.cfg in the wrong directory. Here are my notes (which do work, eventually).

General strategy for getting mtpro fonts to work.

- Run `updmap --verbose` from a dos box.
- Run `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` from a dos box.
- Make sure `Document and Settings/All Users/Application Data/Miktex/2.9/miktex/config` contains the file `updmap.cfg` with the correct contents.

Note: the installation puts it in `myname/Application Data/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/config/`

Put in All Users. This seems to have done the trick.

Comment: It seems you mixed up administrative and user mode installation, cf. [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex).

Comment: @Speravir Not my mix up --- I installed it for all users, but then initexmf assumed otherwise. Until I moved the file, I got the same error as OP.

Comment: No: You didn’t add the option `--admin`, so you were in user mode.

Comment: @Speravir I'm upvoting this because it draws attention to what on my setup seems to have to do with so-called "shadow copies" that Windows makes in the mysterious and hidden "C:\Users\<username>\AppData" directory. I know that this may be covered by Speravir's links, so anyone feel free to add info or edit things to clarify my understanding.

Comment: Please can anyone guide me through this process? I am finding it really difficult to load mtpro2 and I don't understand your comments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Created `C:\Local TeX Files`. 
   Put zipped fonts distribution in this directory and unzipped there.
2. Click Start → Programs → MiKTeX 2.9 → Maintenance → Settings to open the MiKTeX Options window, Click on the Roots tab. The Roots page shows the list of currently registered root directories.

   Click Add. In the following dialog box , browse to `C:\Local TeX Files` and click OK. The root directory will be appended to the list.

   You can move `C:\Local TeX Files` before the installation directory, if you want to prioritize your own files. Click `C:\Local TeX Files` to select the list entry. Then click Up to move it before the installation directory.
3. In the directory...\miktex 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
   at the command line, Run
   "initexmf --edit-config-file updmap"

a Notepad window is opened, add the line (no quote):

"Map mtpro2.map #localtexmf\dvips\mtpro2\mtpro2.map"

Then save and exit.

4. In the directory...\miktex 2.9\miktex\bin\x64... Run updmap.exe
5. Do somethings as the step 2, Click on the General tab, click Refresh FNDB, click Update Formats.