# Installing fonts for yhmath on MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex, yhmath

I'd like to use the [yhmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/yhmath) (pdf [documentation](http://www.cs.brown.edu/system/software/latex/doc/yhmath.pdf)), but it requires the installation of new fonts. This is beyond my knowledge level, and I'd really appreciate some help.

I downloaded the CTAN files as zip, and also installed the package through the package manager on MiKTeX, but I don't know how to proceed to install the fonts required for the package.

*MiKTeX 2.9 with pdflatex on Windows 7 64-bit*

**EDIT:** Following Harish Kumar's link, and Speravir's advise; I created a new directory localtexmf and copied the .vf file to the folder suggested by Speravir. I did the same for the .pfa file. Then I added localtexmf to the Roots in the MiKTeX options, and refreshed the FNDB (as well as updated formats). However, when I run my code I still get the warning "Font shape 'OMX/yhex/m/n' undefined." Speravir suggested that it's a bug with MiKTeX, but is there a way to get around that in the meantime?

Comment: Will http://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html be useful?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Without typo: `mpm --install=yhmath` (@Gal: That’s the command line call for the package installation).

Comment: @HarishKumar mpm --instal=yhmath just prints that the package is already installed (I installed the package through the package manager earlier). My code doesn't produce any errors, just the warning message that a font shape is undefined...

Comment: @Gal: If `yhmath`already was installed, it is strange then, that the font files aren’t installed (I don’t speak about the missing font file `OMXyhex.fd`). Regarding your edit: The file `yhcmex10.tfm` belongs to `<localtexmf\fonts\tfm\public\yhmath` and `yhcmex10.vf` to `<localtexmf>\fonts\vf\public\yhmath`. But the missing file has the extension `.fd`, and in my answer you can read, how to get around.

Comment: I noticed just now, that in MiKTeX all MetaFont files are missing, too! I will edit my answer in a moment.

Comment: @Speravir I don't really know if it's related but in the MiKTeX options under the tab Formats, there are all sorts of keys, including metafonts.

Comment: I know, as long as in the row “Attributes” for the line “Metafonts” there is an empty entry, i.e. **not** an “exclude”, everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Update:* The following is obsolete.** The missing file `OMXyhex.fd` was added on MiKTeX update from Dec 5 2012.

---

*Actually I must confess, that “yhmath” works with some issues* (see [MikTeX 2.9 can not find font yrcmex10 of yhmath package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82655)). I also noticed, that on CTAN there are two `yhmath.zip`! The OP downloaded [the other](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/yhmath.zip) compared to me (link see below), and this is the one used in MiKTeX. So the problem seems to be a **bug in `yhmath`**!

I let stand the following for reference reasons.

I would consider the missing font file `OMXyhex.fd` <strike>and the missing whole bunch of MetaFont files as a bug. It should be filed in the</strike> [MiKTeX bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/).

All other files are installed in a *full* MiKTeX installation. You can get them with the Package Manager. Compared with my TeX Live installation in MiKTeX the type1 file is called `yhcmex.pfa`, in TeX Live it is `yhcmex.pfb`, but these are only variants, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts.

If you downloaded the source files in the ZIP file (link: http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/yhmath.zip), you must extract first into a temporary folder and then execute `tex yhmath.ins`on the command line:

```
C:\tempfolder\yhmath>tex yhmath.ins
```

which creates amongst some auxiliary files the font files, optionally followed by `latex yhmath.dtx`, which creates the documentation.

You could temporarily [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) and put the virtual font file `OMXyhex.fd` into the folder `<localtexmf>\tex\latex\yhmath`. The MetaFont files with extension `.mf` belong into `<localtexmf>\source\latex\yhmath\`.

For further action see [MikTeX 2.9 can not find font yrcmex10 of yhmath package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82579/miktex-2-9-can-not-find-font-yrcmex10-of-yhmath-package).

Comment: localtexmf\fonts now has the three directories your indicated (type1, source, tfm, vf) with
source->empty; tfm->yhcmex10, yrcmex10; type1->yhcmex.pfa; vf->yhcmex.vf; in the appropriate subfolders. In addition, I have \localtexmf\tex\... with the yhcmex.vf file. However, I don't have any other type of files except .ins and the .sty for the package (see CTAN). I'm still getting the same warning message.

Comment: Gal, the best is: Make an uninstall of `yhmath`, straightly followed by an re-installation. But because of the missing files it won't work.

Comment: @Gal: See my edit, how to deal with the `.dtx` and `.ins` file.

Comment: I uninstalled and then ran the .ins file, however I get error message "Cannot find yhmath.dtx ". If this is an insurmountable difficulty, it might be time to throw the towel. I'd really like to use yhmath, but in the meantime I'm making do with mtpro-lite...

Comment: If you’ve downloaded the `yhmath.zip`, then there **must** exist the `yhmath.dtx`! But anyway: For “MtPro Lite” see [How to install MathTime Pro 2 fonts on MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74698/how-to-install-mathtime-pro-2-fonts-on-miktex), though the description contains redundant points.

Comment: @speravir: "the" is not the word -- there are *2* yhmath.zip files on ctan.  the distributions (including miktex, fwiw) seem to get this right, taking the font stuff from `ctan:fonts/ymath/` and macros from `ctan:macros/latex/contrib/yhmath`; it's the latter that contains the .dtx and .ins files.  this situation isn't great, but it's what the author sent us (on two separate dates).  there is, i agree, some value in rationalising this situation, but there's the tiresome shortage of hours in the day.   (and i've two macro programming jobs in backlog, too.)

Comment: @wasteofspace: _(misusing the comment system)_ Please see [yrcmex10 problem AFTER December 5, 2012](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86957/yrcmex10-problem-after-december-5-2012). The file `yrcmex10.mf` is **NOT** part of both ZIP files and is **NOT** created on compiling the `yhmath.ins`. Could you add this manually from the packed TeX Live file http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/yhmath.tar.xz , where it belongs, to the other MF font files, please? And in the respective ZIP file, as well?