# MikTeX 2.9 can not find font yrcmex10 of yhmath package

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex, yhmath

*This is a follow-up to [Installing fonts for yhmath on MiKTeX 2.9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82238/installing-fonts-for-yhmath-on-miktex-2-9) .*

Compiling a document, TeXnicCenter with MiKTeX could not make use of the `yrcmex10` font in the `yhmath` package.

I downloaded `yhmath`, ran `latex yhmath.ins`, and created `yhmath.map` by copying another `map` file; then I put my files on a root `C:\localtexmf`, added the root to MiKTeX, edited `updmap.cfg`, updated maps, refreshed Database; but the tests keep failing.

My root is structured as follows:

`\localtexmf\tex\latex\yhmath` has `yhmath.sty` and `OMXyhex.fd`
`\localtexmf\fonts` has five subdirectories:

- `\map\dvips\yhmath` with `yhmath.map`
- `\source\public\yhmath` with `.mf` files
- `\tfm\public\yhmath` with `yhcmex10.tfm` and `yrcmex10.tfm`
- `\type1\public\yhmath` with `yhcmex.pfa` (its name is NOT `yhcmex10.pfa`)
- `\vf\public\yhmath` with `yhcmex10.vf`

`yhmath.map` has the only line

`yrcmex10 Yhcmex <yhcmex.pfa`

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate: [installing-fonts-for-yhmath-on-miktex-2-9](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82238/installing-fonts-for-yhmath-on-miktex-2-9)? [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in egregs edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

***Update:* Obsolete** since Dec 5 2012.

---

Problem solved.

As `yhmath.ins` didn't generate any `.map` file, I previously created `yhmath.map` with Wordpad, which proved to be a mistake: I only obtained a `.txt` file named `yhmath.map`.

So I pasted a file `.map` whatever into `\localtexmf\fonts\map\dvips\yhmath`,
changed it with Wordpad, saved it being careful not to change its format, and renamed as `yhmath.map`. Then I ran `initexmf --mkmaps`, and `kpsewhich` could find `yhmath.map`.

Still MikTex couldn't find `yrcmex10.tfm`.

I eventually discovered that running `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` edited `updmap.cfg` located in `\AppData\Roaming\MikTex\2.9\miktx\config\` directory, while I actually wanted to edit the homonym file in `\Program Files\MikTex 2.9\miktex\config\`. So I copied the file in `\AppData\[...]` and pasted to `\Program Files\[...]`.

Ran `initexmf --mkmaps` again. Ran `testfont.tex` and found the font `yrcmex10.tfm` was avaliable to MikTex.

There is still a minor issue. Creating a `.ps` or a `.dvi` with Texniccenter works fine. A `.pdf` will contain some wrong characters, due to the fact that the embodied font `yhcmex10.tfm` is not avaliable to extract.

Here is a Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
$\wideparen{ab} \widetriangle{ab} \widering{ab}$
\end{document}
```

[image: example output with MiKTeX and TeX Live]

<sup>Image added by Speravir</sup>

Comment: Answer upvoted. Hint for the future: In Wordpad and also Notepad save the names with quotes, so no automatic adition of a file extension happens. Here it would have been `"yhmath.map"`. Regarding the issue try with `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (ansinew only in Windows, if not utf8). Otherwise I think you would need to change the map file, but I don’t know exactly know how.