# How can I standardize my square root signs?

Tags: math-mode

I've noticed that when square root signs get too large, their front leg goes vertical (1), and that otherwise, it angles to the right (2).

How can I standardize all my square root signs to either behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\Delta F_0 &= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\delta F_0}{\delta x_i}\Delta x_i\right)^2}\\[0.2cm]
\Delta F_0 &= \sqrt{6.044 \cdot  10^{-6}\text{m}^2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, I use `\partial` to represent derivatives instead of `\delta`...

Comment: Oh, that's much better. Thank you. (If you can't tell, I'm pretty new to LaTeX)

Answer (score 13):

In general, you can't standardise this:  the over-large ones have to be straight as TeX can not stretch otherwise, for smaller sizes it depends on the font in use, the shape, and how many designed sizes there are is controlled by the font not TeX.

Almost all fonts will use a slanted design for the designed glyphs before TeX falls back to the straight extender, so one way to standardise on sloping design unless you have *really* tall entries is to use a font that has more sizes of designed sqrt size than the original cm fonts. The yhmath font is one such font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,yhmath}
\begin{document}

(1)
\[\Delta F_0 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\delta F_0}{\delta x_i}\Delta x_i\right)^2}\]


(2)
\[\Delta F_0 = \sqrt{6.044 \cdot 10^{-6}\text{m}^2}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I try to use yhmath, it gives me the following error:

    `miktex-makemf: The yrcmex source file could not be found.

Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk: PK font yrcmex10 could not be created.
 )

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file yrcmex10): Font yrcmex10 at 600 not found

 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
texify: pdflatex failed for some reason (see log file).`

Comment: the yhmath fonts are available in scalable format these days so tex shouldn't have to be making pk fonts. I expect miktex package manager can be coaxed into installing the right fonts but I know nothing of miktex (the image I showed was made with a stock texlive 2012 install)

Comment: It seems that the problem with `yhmath` in MiKTeX is a long standing one: see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86957/yrcmex10-problem-after-december-5-2012), or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82238/installing-fonts-for-yhmath-on-miktex-2-9), or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82579/miktex-2-9-can-not-find-font-yrcmex10-of-yhmath-package)