# \sum caused \sqrt to not be slanted

Tags: math-mode

As shown in the MWE below, `\sum` (esp. when the index and lower/upper bounds are defined) is causing the slanty part of the `sqrt` sign to be not slanty. Is there a way to preserve it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\sqrt{{x^i}}
\]
\[
\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}{x^i}}
\]
\[
\sqrt{\sum^{n}{x^i}}
\]
\[
\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^i}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: See also this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87440/… and its answers. The suggestion of the `yhmath` package has not yet been given here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you look carefully you can see that the angle changes if the part below the root sign gets larger until it is vertical. Imho all math fonts will do it. So if you want a slant:  make the content smaller, e.g. by using \nolimits:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{1+ \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1+ \sqrt{1+ \sqrt{1+x}}}}}} 
\]

\[
\sqrt{\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{n}{x^i}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

The only math font package I know that has slanted surds at large sizes is `mtpro2`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

\[
\SQRT{1+ \SQRT{1+ \SQRT{1 + \SQRT{1+ \SQRT{1+ \SQRT{1+x}}}}}}
\]

\[
\SQRT{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^i}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that `\SQRT` should be used for this to work. Unfortunately, adapting this to other font families would be *very* complicated. The package changes *all* fonts to be Times like.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

With MinionMath-Regular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{MinionMath-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}

\[
  \sqrt{{x^i}}
\]
\[
  \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}{x^i}}
\]
\[
  \sqrt{\sum^{n}{x^i}}
\]
\[
  \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^i}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Two suggestions:

- You could affix `\nolimits` to `\sum`, to force LateX to set the limits of summation to the side rather than above and below the summation symbol. That way, the surds will be noticeably less steep *and* their overall height will be much reduced, reducing their visual dominance. Of course, if you side-set the limits of summation, the formulas will take up more *horizontal* space. (I just noticed that this suggestion is also made in the second half of Ulrike's answer.)
- If you want to keep the limits of summation above and below the summation symbol, you could switch to using large parentheses and exponential notation to indicate that square roots are being taken. If you go this route, be sure to use `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` and not `\left(` and `\right`, as otherwise the parentheses would become too large from a typographic/aesthetic point of view.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1} x^i} \quad \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^i}
\quad\mbox{vs.}\quad
% use of "\nolimits"
\sqrt{\sum\nolimits_{i=1} x^i} \quad \sqrt{\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n} x^i}
\quad\mbox{vs.}\quad
% use of parenthetic notation
\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1} x^i \!\biggr)^{\!1/2} \quad 
\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^i \!\biggr)^{\!1/2}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

We could do it, but it would be wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\[
\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^i}}
\]
\[
\scalebox{2}{$\displaystyle\sqrt{\scalebox{0.5}{$\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x^i}$}}$}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: sqare roots]

Comment: It looks **horrible**. The surd sign looks far too bold and it is taking up far too much space.

Comment: @ceilingcat It's wrong because the thickness of the surd and the horizontal stroke following the surd ends up being twice as thick (vertically)  as it ought.  I should know, because I contemplated doing the same fix LOL!

Comment: I think both look horrible.

Comment: Mostly, it just wastes space.  With really long equations, saving space it everything.  One can reduce the boldness using scales closer to 1 (like 0.8 and 1.25).