# Horizontal rule on tall radical sign has segments of different thicknesses

Tags: math-mode, sqrt

I wonder how I can generate a document, as shown below, in which the horizontal rule for the radical does not comprise two segments of differing thicknesses.

I'm working on Ubuntu 22.04. `latex --version` reports the following:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

`xdvi --version` reports the following:

```
xdvik version 22.87.04 (Xaw toolkit)
Libraries: kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev, freetype version 2.11.1
```

`evince --version` reports the following:

```
GNOME Document Viewer 42.3
```

`dvipdfm --version` reports, in part, the following:

```
This is dvipdfm Version 20210609 by the DVIPDFMx project team,
modified for TeX Live,
an extended version of dvipdfm-0.13.2c developed by Mark A. Wicks.
```

I find the following document,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n x_i}
\]
\end{document}
```

is displayed with a the horizontal rule being two segments of different thicknesses, as shown in this image:

[image]

after being displayed, variously, by

```
$ latex t.tex
$ dvipds t.dvi
$ gv t.ps
```

or

```
$ latex t.tex
$ dvipdfm t.dvi
$ evince t.pdf
```

or

```
$ latex t.tex
$ xdvi t.dvi
```

In each case, I see the horizontal rule comprising two segments of different thicknesses, as shown in the embedded image.

This question is my second attempt; for the record, the previous attempt might be viewable at: [Tall \sqrt has noticeable blicky on horizontal bar due to joining unaligned segments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693282/tall-sqrt-has-noticeable-blicky-on-horizontal-bar-due-to-joining-unaligned-segm)

See also [\sum caused \sqrt to not be slanted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291216/sum-caused-sqrt-to-not-be-slanted) which shows, in the fourth image, the same problem as I've described here.

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle says (well, now his comment seems to be removed) this is due to the left part being a glyph in the font and the rule being a rule (not from font), and that causes problems in viewers. Making the bar out of glyphs instead of a rule [might help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wtDP.png) (this is a blown up (1600%) screenshot from the formula). But I do not think that is available in LaTeX.