# yrcmex10 problem AFTER December 5, 2012

Tags: miktex, yhmath

I updated MiKTeX and everything. I get this:

```
(C:\Users\Bora\Desktop\aaa\12.23.2011.aux)Trying to make PK font yrcmex10 at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The yrcmex source file could not be found.

Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font yrcmex10 could not be created.
 )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 67 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file yrcmex10): Font yrcmex10 at 600 not foun
d
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\newcommand{\BEL}[1]{\text{\boldmath ${\mathsf{L}\!\negmedspace\negmedspace\mathsf{L}}_{#1}$}} 
\usepackage{yhmath} 
\usepackage{bm} 

\begin{document} 
\[ \big((\forall y \in x)A^{\BEL{\alpha}}(x|y) A^{\BEL{\alpha}}\big) \] 
\end{document}
```

My directories are like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we can try it on our own computers?

Comment: Is your question a follow-up question to [installing fonts for yhmath on miktex 2.9?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82238/installing-fonts-for-yhmath-on-miktex-2-9?rq=1)?

Comment: It's not a follow-up question (I don't think?). I searched for my problem first, and saw that people's problems were solved after December 5, that's why I wrote the title that way. BTW please ignore the patterns package. You only need the bm and the yhmath packages. I cannot edit the above any more.

Comment: The problem is the \big command up there. If I remove it, the problem disappears.

Comment: I corrected the MWE above. We only need bm and yhmath packages. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: There seems to be an mf-file missing (yrcmex10.mf). My TeXLive contains it but I have no idea where it got it from. The dtx and the ins of yhmath doesn't mention it. The yhmath package contains also a pfa, but this seems to be defect.

Comment: I installed it from MikTeX's Package Manager and updated it from MikTeX's Update Manager, not manually. So is it a bug then? Is there a place I can put the mf file manually? The directories are as above.

Comment: What is the difference between yrcmex10.mf and yrcmex10.tfm? Maybe they got rid of the .mf in the latest version? Can you send me the mf file you have?

Comment: I apparently have the yrcmex10.mf in my texmf/fonts/source/public/yhmath I just realized.

Comment: My yrcmex10.mf seems to be corrupt. I can open yhcmex10.mf with TexWorks and it has actually sensible code in it, whereas opening yrcmex10.mf I get weird garbled symbols. It does say TEX MATH EXTENSION YRCMEX but the rest of it are weird symbols.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled yhmath from a different online repository, no change.

Comment: Added to MiKTeX Bug Tracker: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2201/

Comment: Copying yrcmex10.mf from http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/yhmath.tar.xz fixed the problem. I also had no map file for yhmath, I copied that too. Now my file compiles.

Comment: Make a copy of `yhcmex10.mf` and rename it as `yrcmex10.mf` (put it in the same directory `...\fonts\source\public\yhmath` or equivalent for `.mf` files) and refresh the filename database. Try again and tell me.