# mtpro package installation for MiKTeX

Tags: math-mode, installing, miktex, mtpro

I want to use upright greek letters in times text. I am unable to install `mtpro` package installation for MikTex 2.9

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a bit more information as to what you've done so far. E.g., did you download the full or the "lite" version of the pacakge? Where in the installation process (which is explained in one of the user guides) did you get stuck?

Comment: In addition to Mico: There should be not significant difference to [How to install MathTime Pro 2 fonts on MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74698). See also [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063).