# Installing Minion Pro El Capitan

Tags: fonts, installing, mac, minionpro

I've tried all of the obvious places googling. I think that I'm not able to edit the `updmap.cfg` file correctly because running `updmap-sys` seems to only know about my old tex distribution `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: look at the 5th step http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74851/92620

Comment: Don't understand what you say with "El Capitan".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install MathTime Pro 2 fonts on MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74698/how-to-install-mathtime-pro-2-fonts-on-miktex)

Comment: El Capitan is an operating system on Macs. MikTex is a Tex distribution for Windows

Comment: Maybe is something about " On recent teTeX distributions you might have to call updmap-sys instead
of updmap depending on in which tree you installed the files. "