# Installing mtpro2lite

Tags: mtpro

Tried installing the  mtpro2lite font using the procedure given here in this link: https://github.com/jamespfennell/mathtime-installer/

But i am getting the following error. Kindly help.

https://github.com/jamespfennell/mathtime-installer/

```
Wednesday 26 May 2021 06:55:19 AM IST
TeX information:
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
updmap.cfg is at /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
The texmf directory for fonts is /usr/local/share/texmf
confirm_input(): Checking mtp2lite.zip.
File exists and is a zip file.
require_comment(): testing to see if unzip is installed
Output of command -v: /usr/bin/unzip
Command found
Temporary directory at ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf.
Running command `unzip mtp2lite.zip -d ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf`.
------------------------[ OUTPUT OF: unzip ]---------------------------------------------
Archive:  mtp2lite.zip
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/EULA-MTPro2Lite.txt  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/templates/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/templates/LaTeX Article MTPro2.tex  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/templates/LaTeX Article MTPro2Lite.tex  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/templates/MTPro2 LaTeX test.tex  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/templates/Plain MTPro2.tex  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/EULA-MTPro2.txt  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/EULA-MTPro2Lite.txt  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/guide2.pdf  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/mtpro2.pdf  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/testMTP2LaTeX.pdf  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/testMTP2LaTeX.tex  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/dvips/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/dvips/mtpro2/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/dvips/mtpro2/mtpro2.map  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/map/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/mtpro2/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/mtpro2/mtpro2.map  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exa.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exe.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exf.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exg.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mbf.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mbs.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mbt.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mif.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mis.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mit.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2syf.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2sys.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2syt.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2xl.tfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2xxxl.tfm  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exa.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exa.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exe.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exe.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exf.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exf.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exg.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exg.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mbf.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mbf.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mbs.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mbs.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mbt.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mbt.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mif.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mif.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mis.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mis.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mit.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2mit.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2syf.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2syf.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2sys.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2sys.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2syt.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2syt.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2xl.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2xl.pfm  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2xxxl.pfb  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2xxxl.pfm  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/source/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/source/latex/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/source/latex/mtpro2/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/source/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.dtx  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/source/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.ins  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/omslbm.fd  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/umt2bb.fd  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/umt2hrb.fd  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/umt2mf.fd  
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/umt2ms.fd  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/plain/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/plain/mtpro2/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/plain/mtpro2/mtp2.tex  
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tpm/
   creating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tpm/package/
  inflating: ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/tpm/package/mtp2lite.tpm  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Removing previous MTPro2 files, as a precaution.
Removing MTPro2 files from /usr/local/share/texmf.
Coping all files in ./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/texmf/ to /usr/local/share/texmf/.
Removing the temporary directory.
Updating TeX Live
------------------------[ OUTPUT OF: texhash ]---------------------------------------------
texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
------------------------[ OUTPUT OF: updmap-sys --disable mt-belleek.map --nomkmap ]-------
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap [WARNING]: map file not present, nothing to disable: mt-belleek.map
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
------------------------[ OUTPUT OF: updmap-sys --disable mt-belleek.map --nomkmap ]-------
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
------------------------[ OUTPUT OF: updmap-sys --disable mt-yy.map --nomkmap ]------------
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap [WARNING]: map file not present, nothing to disable: mt-yy.map
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
------------------------[ OUTPUT OF: updmap-sys --disable mt-plus.map --nomkmap ]----------
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap [WARNING]: map file not present, nothing to disable: mt-plus.map
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
------------------------[ OUTPUT OF: updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map ]------------------
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map mtpro2 present in updcfg file.
------------------------[ OUTPUT OF: updmap-sys ]------------------------------------------
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:     mtpro2.map (in /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Installed.
Temporary file at ./mtpro2-texlive_tmptex_JQHaGFU4.tex.
Running pdflatex on the following code in ./mtpro2-texlive_tmptex_JQHaGFU4.tex:
        \documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
        \usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
        \selectfont
        \begin{document}
        \section{New LaTeX document}
        Your new LaTeX document is ready to edit.
        $$x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
        \end{document}
./mtpro2-texlive_tmptex_JQHaGFU4.tex:4: Emergency stop. ./mtpro2-texlive_tmptex_JQHaGFU4.tex:4: ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PD
Error in compilation; outputting now
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mtpro2-texlive_tmptex_JQHaGFU4.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/txfonts.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `mtpro2.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
./mtpro2-texlive_tmptex_JQHaGFU4.tex:4: Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.4         \selectfont
                 ^^M
./mtpro2-texlive_tmptex_JQHaGFU4.tex:4:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PD
F file produced!
Transcript written on mtpro2-texlive_tmptex_JQHaGFU4.log.
```

Comment: I never tried that steps. I guess there is a different approach to install the lite version. This guides worked with me: https://pctex.com/kb/62.html (texlive) or https://pctex.com/kb/56.html (Miktex). Also [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74698/how-to-install-mathtime-pro-2-fonts-on-miktex] may help you.

Comment: well the script puts everything into the temporary place `/mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/mtp2lite/texmf/`, but then at the end it copies from `./mtpro2-texlive_tmpdir_GCUhXVQf/texmf/`, so probably nothing is copied at all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Emm. Ok so what should i do in order to get that package working?

Comment: well you need to get the files in the right place. The list shows you where they belong.  I think texlive 2019 already knows auxtrees, so you could unpack the zip somewhere and then add the root of the tree with `tlmgr conf auxtrees add path/to/mtp2lite/texmf`.  Check if the style it found. Then you should as last step activate the map file with `updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry i fail to understand a lot of things. "root of the tree, auxtree" such terms i dont understand only.

Comment: Would be really glad if you can take me through the installation procedures elaborately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have  zip file. Unpack it somewhere (outside your tex system). It contains a texmf folder:

[image]

Note the path to this texmf. It should be something like `/usr/whatever/something/mtp2lite/texmf/`

Then run in a terminal

```
 tlmgr conf auxtrees add /usr/whatever/something/mtp2lite/texmf
```

replace the path with the real path to the texmf.

Then check if the style if found by using

```
 kpsewhich mtpro2.sty
```

If this is successfull run

```
 updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map
```

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborate answer. Let me try and get back. Apologies for pestering you.

Comment: chandru1@chandru-hp:~$  updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.

Comment: It is giving me this message. Am i ok now?

Comment: no idea, perhaps you already had the map, try it.

Comment: Nopes. It says mtpro2.sty not found :(

Comment: then you did step three before doing the check. If kpsewhich doesn't find the style than step one is wrong.

Comment: I did step 2 but no error came. When i did step 2 it just  didnt give me any output so i continued with step 3

Comment: there is no error, it should find the file. If it doesn't report anything it doesn't find it. Please check the documentation of kpsewhich.

Comment: Fine. Now what should i do?

Comment: check if you really used the right path, and if the files are really in the texmf.

Comment: Quite sure i used the right path. And the files in the texmf (of mtpro2lite file)  are : doc, dvips,fonts,source tex and tpm

Comment: then show a screenshot which shows the path, and show the output of the tlmgr command.

Comment: Sure. Hold on 2mins

Comment: Here goes the screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/TdMR9fq This is the output after i retried again.

Comment: why sudo? Does it error without it? Also I can't see the content of the texmf.

Comment: Yes. It asks me to become root. https://imgur.com/a/GXTWp75 Here are the contents.

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: Hey, the mtpro2.sty file is there. I searched manually. It is in the folder /home/chandru1/mtp2lite/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty though not sure  why kpsewhich doens't find it out. Can we proceed now?

Comment: Why no replies from you? :(

Comment: I do also have other things to do. So please don't push around. Actually I think the path you used for the tlmgr command is wrong, the real path is `/home/....`  and not `/usr/home/...`.

Comment: Nope same error. Nothing changes. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/1e5wmj8

Comment: Just a gentle reminder so that you don't forget : Don't forget to help, whenever you have time :)

Comment: sorry I can't help more. I don't know why the tree is not used for you. You could try `texhash`, but I don't think that it will help. Basically you only have to copy the files somewhere where tex can find them (keeping the structure of the folders), so try to move them into your texmfhome or texmf-local.

Comment: Being naive i think for me it's hard unless and until someone tells me what all file where I have to copy. I think it's too much to ask. But you have helped a great deal. Thanks for that. Take care.

Comment: look it is easy you have a file in texmf/tex/latex/xx/...  and this should go into texmfhome/tex/latex/xx/..., simply copy the structure.

Comment: You mean all the contents of the mt2lite directory should be copied to the home/texmf directly accordingly?

Comment: Workingggggggggggggggggg!!!! Thankkkkksss a tonnnnnnnnnn!!! :)

Comment: @C.S. Could you please add the steps which worked for you.?