# Using MathTime 2 Lite with MacTeX on Big Sur

Tags: math-mode, fonts, texlive, mactex, mathtime

I have Big Sur and am using MacTeX. I'm trying to use the MathTime 2 Lite fonts.

I downloaded the package from CTAN and followed the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598605/installing-mtpro2lite?r=SearchResults), but doesn't work. I also tried the [installer](https://github.com/jamespfennell/mathtime-installer) but apparently I don't have the neccessary files. (I can't download it from the official downloads page from PCTeX, as the server doesn't respond to my request and I can't access the website.)

What should I do? (And by the way, I can't use other Times math fonts, as I'm fond of MathTime's individually designed large operators.)

### Steps to reproduce

1. Install the package from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite?lang=en) and place the `texmf` folder in `/Users/[username]/Library/`.
2. Create a `.tex` file with this code:

   ```tex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
   \usepackage{mathtools}
   \begin{document}
   \[ \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (y^i -x^i )^2 } \quad \text{vs.}\quad \SQRT{\sum_{i=1}^n (y^i -x^i )^2 } \]
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Thanks! My distribution is TeX Live and I updated it about 6 months ago. My TeX engine is pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Please try updating your TeX distribution to [MacTeX2021](https://tug.org/mactex/) and updating all LaTeX packages (via `sudo tlmgr upate --self --all` from a command window) before you go any further. Please advise when you've finished that step and whether you've encountered any warning or error messages.

Comment: I will do that, but just curious, why MacTeX? Is there a difference with TeX Live?

Comment: MacTeX *is* TeXLive plus a few MacOS-specific goodies.

Comment: What, exactly, did you do that didn't work?

Comment: I still got an error message: `! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.138 \alloc@0\count\countdef\insc@unt\pointcount@`

Comment: that is not an installation error but due to a bug in the style. But imho it shouldn't appear in a current texlive, you will have to make a small complete example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a complete example?

Comment: something that starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document} and allows us to test if we can reproduce the error. And you should me ping me with @UlrikeFischer if you want me to see that you answered.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, I've added the MWE.

Comment: Add also the log file of your example so the we can compare with our log.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I'm good. I just forgot to add the two lines `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in my actual document. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding

```tex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

works.