# How to install "TeX Gyre Schola" font for MiKTeX?

Tags: fonts, packages, installing, miktex

I've followed the guide:
http://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

and downloaded the font files from:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/tex-gyre/

Now there are 72 `.map` files under the `map` folder of `tex-gyre` folder.

What is the correct `.map` file should I use for `Map newfont.map`

---

Second question is: 
For some fonts, there is only one `.map` file, so I didn't have problem to run `initexmf`  command. But after follow all the steps in tug's guide, it still does not work properly. Is there anything besides the guide? (All font files I downloaded contains "tex" and "fonts" two folders, I just put it in a single folder and renamed it after the font's name. Then update the MiKTeX follows the guide. (Anything wrong so far?)

The font installation really drives me crazy...

Comment: Install the package [tex-gyre](http://miktex.org/packages/tex-gyre) using the MiKTeX package manager.

Comment: Thanks egreg, it worked using the package manager. But I still prefer to know the details of which .map file should one use when install the fonts. Thanks.

Comment: Manual installation of fonts is often a pain in the neck: you have to store correctly TFM, VF, Type1 and LaTeX files, updating the filename database and the map files. However, the relevant map files are those with the simpler names: `q??.map`

Comment: I tried the first one in the .map list on the other machine. it worked! Thanks egreg.

Comment: You may supply a self-answer showing what you did.

Comment: @egreg Perhaps write an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Let's see a simpler example than the TeX Gyre set of fonts and consider OpenSans, assuming it's not delivered as part of the TeX distribution.

The directory on CTAN form a rather complex subtree:

```
opensans/
  doc/
  fonts/
  source/
  tex/
```

Each one of the four subdirectories denotes a part of the TeX tree where we need to install the files; on TeX Live it would be

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

and the structure should be created if still not existent. So, for example, at the end we'll have

```
/usr/
  local/
    texlive/
      texmf-local/
        doc/
          fonts/
            opensans/
              CHANGES
              README
              opensans-samples.pdf
              opensans-samples.tex
              opensans.pdf
              opensans.tex

        fonts/
          ...
```

After having populated the directories one has to teach TeX Live about the new font:

```
sudo mktexlsr
sudo updmap-sys --enable-map opensans.map
```

The second operation may be better performed, on TeX Live 2012 (or later) by editing the file

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

(creating it if non existent) adding the line

```
Map opensans.map
```

and running

```
sudo updmap-sys
```

afterwards.

Similar operations should be made on MiKTeX (Update File Name Database for the first and something based on `initexmf` from a command shell for the second). The biggest complication with MiKTeX is that it doesn't have a "local" TeX tree by default, but it should not be so complex to define one.

Why using the "local" tree? Because it doesn't strictly belong to the TeX distribution, so it won't be touched by later updates to the distribution.

For the TeX Gyre fonts the situation is similar, but with the complication that there is no "global" map file, so one should perform all the above steps and add to the "local" updmap.cfg the lines

```
Map qag.map
Map qbk.map
Map qcr.map
Map qcs.map
Map qhv.map
Map qpl.map
Map qtm.map
Map qzc.map
```

### Comments

Manually installing fonts can be a pain in the neck. Much better to stick with the TeX distribution package manager (`tlmgr` for TeX Live or MiKTeX's) if the fonts are included in the distribution.

In any case I recommend using the "local" tree, whenever possible: installing fonts in a "personal tree" (under `~/texmf/` on Unix systems with TeX Live or `~/Library/texmf` with MacTeX or something else with MiKTeX) requires all the steps above in the correct tree and to run `updmap` instead of `updmap-sys`, with the problem that font related updates to the main tree will *not* be reflected in the personal map files, so that `updmap` has to be run manually in those cases.

Comment: I hope, you find it useful, too: [Purpose of local texmf trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/purpose-of-local-texmf-trees).