# Where can I find the scrpage.cfg file?

Tags: scrpage2

I want to put my pagestyles in the `scrpage.cfg` file but I don't know where this file is or where I have to put this after creating it.

Can somebody answer me this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file does not exist by default.  It should be placed anywhere the usual tex search mechanisms will find files.  As it is mostly intended for local configuration, the natural place would be the current directory of the current project.

If you want to make it available for all your projects then you should place in the local texmf tree.  The exact details of this will depend on which system you are using, see .g. [Purpose of local texmf trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69487/15925) and the questions linked from there