# Venn diagram outlines

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I am using the [`venndiagram`](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram/venndiagram.pdf) package to... well, draw Venn diagrams.

I know it's considered a very basic package, but it works well for my purposes.

Except for one thing.

Both the `venndiagram2sets` and `venndiagram3sets` environments introduced by the package automatically draw rectangular outlines around the diagrams.

This is defined by the following line in the code:

```
\draw (venn bottom left) rectangle (\@venn@w,\@venn@h);
```

Is there any way to deactivate this?

Comment: I think the easiest solution will be to copy venndiagram.sty on a local folder, comment out this line and be sure your system loads your version of venndiagram.

Comment: After that you can write to venndiagram author and suggest to add an option to avoid these rectangles.

Comment: How can I make sure that my system loads the local *.sty?

Comment: TeX systems use a `local` folder when you can store your own or modified packages. But if you store the modified .sty inside your working folder, this version will be loaded. In any case, you can read the .log file where all loaded packages are detailed with information about their path.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/purpose-of-local-texmf-trees?rq=1

Comment: You were right, it was enough to store it in my local folder. Perhaps you can post all of the above comments as an answer so I can upvote it? They seem to have solved the problem quite neatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quickly reading through `venndiagram.sty`, it seems to me that these rectangles around diagrams are hardcoded with

```
\draw (venn bottom left) rectangle (\@venn@w,\@venn@h);
```

and there is no special color to fade or option to skip drawing them. Therefore the best solution I can provide is to copy `venndiagram.sty` in your working folder and comment out these lines.

If you store modified `.sty` files in same folder as your document, the modified package will be loaded instead of the `official` one.

If you have to use the modified package with documents in different folders, will be better to use a `local texmf tree` ([Purpose of local texmf trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/purpose-of-local-texmf-trees?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and store your version in it. This way you don't have to keep a copy inside every working folder.

Finally, if you consider that this modification could be usefull, you can always write to packege author and suggest to include in future versions of `venndiagram`.

Answer (score 7):

Another option could be to use `xpatch` to patch those two environments, either removing the line altogether, or adding a style to the path, like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\tikzset{
  vennframe/.style={draw=none} % define a new style for the frames
}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\endvenndiagram3sets}
{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\@venn@w,\@venn@h);} % replace this
{\draw [vennframe] (0,0) rectangle (\@venn@w,\@venn@h);} % with this -- add the style
{}{}

\xpatchcmd{\endvenndiagram2sets}
{\draw (venn bottom left) rectangle (\@venn@w,\@venn@h);}
{\draw [vennframe] (venn bottom left) rectangle (\@venn@w,\@venn@h);}
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}
\fillA \fillB \fillC
\end{venndiagram3sets}

\begin{venndiagram2sets}
\fillA \fillB
\end{venndiagram2sets}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Version 1.2 (2018-06-07)¹ has a new boolean option `showframe` that governs whether to use `\draw` or `\path` for the frame. (The bounding rectangle always needs to be defined but this option now allows it to be hidden.)

---

¹Allow a few days for the new version to reach the TeX distributions.