# Drawing Venn diagrams that is not specifically always two circles

Tags: draw, venn-diagrams

I am wondering about package or a simple way to draw Venn diagrams. I need to draw the following examples:

[image]

and as you can see my hand drawing skills are not up to the task :)

I have found the package named `venndiagram` and it seem to be able to help me with 4 and 5 but not the rest. I mean sometimes I want to only show one of the circles, sometimes none of the circles, sometimes overlapping, sometimes not and so on. I also found a package named just `venn` but it seems to have a not so satisfactory documentation so I don't know if it could help me or not. To me this seems like something people would do from time to time so I was hoping someone could suggest something else?

Comment: Seems there are no easy ways around this except handcrafting in tikz. Is that cause for closing?

Comment: I think this question is sufficiently different, because it asks about using the `venndiagram` package instead of using only `tikz`, so I voted for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some options to the original code using `draw` and `fill` parameters for the circles and the rectangle. Modifying the code on the fly can be done using the `xpatch` package, similar to [Venn diagram outlines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435368/venn-diagram-outlines).

Then you can set the commands used in those parameters to values that correspond to the diagram that you want to draw. Using `draw=none` and an empty label a circle can be removed from the diagram, and `fill=white` makes a circle visible if the rectangle is filled with `fill=lightgray`. To resume drawing 'normal' diagrams you need to reset the macros to the default values.

Note that #6 does not need any modifications, this can be done by setting the provided key `overlap` to a negative value.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\def\framefill{none}
\def\afill{none}
\def\bfill{none}
\def\adraw{black}
\def\bdraw{black}

\makeatletter
% patch drawing of A and B
\xpatchcmd{\endvenndiagram2sets}
{%
\draw (\@venn@Ax,\@venn@Ay) circle (\@venn@radius);
\draw (\@venn@Bx,\@venn@By) circle (\@venn@radius);
}
{
\draw [draw=\adraw, fill=\afill] (\@venn@Ax,\@venn@Ay) circle (\@venn@radius);
\draw [draw=\bdraw, fill=\bfill] (\@venn@Bx,\@venn@By) circle (\@venn@radius);
}
{\typeout{patch ok}}{\typeout{patch failed}}
% patch frame
\xpatchcmd{\endvenndiagram2sets}
{\draw (venn bottom left) rectangle (\@venn@w,\@venn@h);}
{\draw [fill=\framefill] (venn bottom left) rectangle (\@venn@w,\@venn@h);}
{\typeout{patch ok}}{\typeout{patch failed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}
\fillA \fillB
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}
\fillACapB
\end{venndiagram2sets}

\begin{venndiagram2sets}[overlap=-0.75cm]
\fillA \fillB
\end{venndiagram2sets}

\def\bdraw{none}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelB={}]
\fillA
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\def\framefill{lightgray}
\def\afill{white}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelB={$A^c$}]
\end{venndiagram2sets}

\def\afill{none}
\def\adraw{none}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelA={},labelB={}]
\end{venndiagram2sets}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]