# Miktex randomly fails on install

Tags: installing, miktex

Everytime I try to install miktex it fails, but in different places.  I tried restarting the computer, running admin, nothing works.  The TexStudio installs fine, but doesnt compile the document (i assume since latex is not being installed).  The consistency I do see seems to be with the fonts folder

the error log is like so:

```
extracting files from embrac.tar.lzma...
extracting files from emerald.cab...

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Extractor\CabExtractor.cpp
  source line: 506
  message: The file could not be extracted.
  info: texmf\fonts\tfm\emerald\fjdmw8c.tfm
```

[image]

Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: [Cannot install MiKTeX 2.9 after a new Windows installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162364)

Comment: Looks BTW like a corrupted file, either the CAB extraction part of the installer or the CAB file itself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that is either not TeX related or can definitively answered only by the MiKTeX developer.

Comment: Before I forget: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Sorry this was off topic.  If it helps anyone else, The first link Speravir added had a solution, which was installing to a different drive, which worked for me.