# Permission denied: path="C/program Files/MiKTeX 2.9\doc/bibitex/apalike/apalike.doc

Tags: errors, miktex

While installing MiKTeX this error is coming:

> Permission denied: `path="C/program Files/MiKTeX 2.9\doc/bibitex/apalike/apalike.doc`

My OS version is Windows 7 Ultimate and I downloaded complete MiKTeX files from http://miktex.org using 64bit net installer option.

Then, during installation, it is showing this error. (Earlier I had installed MiKTeX and then deleted all files related to it, since it was not possible to uninstall it completely.)

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format (e.g. you do not need to display your email). `Permission denied` is more a MS-Windows related issue. Are you installing MikTeX with an administrator-priviledges?

Comment: (I've trimmed your question a bit for clarity: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. When you'll get an answer, [accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.)

Comment: I think this answer has the possible reasons the installation fails: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162364/43189 . Try disabling the antivirus first. If no luck, google for 'miktex installation error permission denied' - you'll get some more pointers.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors here.

First: a path for windows 64 bit has to look like `c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\bibtex\apalike\apalike.doc` and not yours `path="C/program Files/MiKTeX 2.9\doc/bibitex/apalike/apalike.doc`. you missed `:` and mixed `\` and `/`.

In LaTeX it could be that the path is printed with the linux path delimiter `/`. But if there is a mixing of both, that is an error, usually caused by manual typing an path ...

Second: where does your cited `bibitex` comes from? I guess a typo? I corrected it above to `bibtex` ...

Third: You did not tell which MiKTeX version you installed.  Please add this information to your question.

Because there are some informations missing, I can only guess.  Please proof and report the result.

For me it seems you used a wrong typed path inserted for the MiKTeX installer.

Check the resulting installation log file and report the result.

Comment: windows takes forward/backward slashes mixed or not as folder sep since the beginning. MiKTeX does this uncommon thing to report/log mixed slashes. `bibitex` leads to believe it was a manually typed path in this question.  The missing `:` would not have lead to this error, only to installation to an unwanted place/path. An invalid path would have stopped installation from the start but the OP said "*during* installation". I suppose MiKTeX is 2.9 (from path),  likely the latest (from "I downloaded"). When installation stops at  doc, dll, exe or other win "goodies",  the AV is the main suspect.