# Global configuration files in LaTeX

Tags: package-writing, class-options

Just wanna know if there is posible to have some kind of "configuration file" on LaTeX. Like a properties file on Java.

Recently I changed my email address, so i need to replace it on every document I'd created until now... Since I'm creating several kind of documents: tech reports, thesis, beamer presentations, articles, posters, and so on, I would like to have a single file with peronal/college data:

```
            _name=Derpina Derpson
            _email=myemail@campus.edu
            _univname=My college name
            _collegeURL=http://mycollege.edu
            .
            .
            .
            _collegeLogo=./figures/logo.jpg
            _declaration=The content of this document is...
```

So in my documents I could have something like: `\author{_name}`.

This way I could be able to handle all that common information in one file. It is possible?, can somebody tell me how?

I'm not a LaTeX expert. As far as I understand, I could do this through a common CLS file. Nevertheless, each document has different structure (article, book, beamer presentation, lettersize, custom paper size, twoside, oneside, etc.).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

rather than through a .cls you should do this using a .sty file (a ›package‹). `mystyle.sty` would look something like this:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\newcommand*{\myname}{Derpina Derpson}
\newcommand*{\mymail}{myemail@campus.edu}
\endinput
```

and in your documents, you simply load that package and have access to the things defined there:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\myname
\mymail
\end{document}
```

if you place that package in your `texmflocal` directory, it will be available from anywhere (i.e., it doesn't have to be in the same place that your document is in). Don't forget to run `texhash` or the like to make TeX aware of that new file in its tree.

Comment: This is a really stupid question, but where do/would you save this config file? I.e. where does the LaTeX compiler know to look?

Comment: you probably have a `texmflocal`directory somewhere in your installation. That's where you put that file.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to create a separate class, just a package or even a regular input file.

You could create a file, say `myconfig.tex`, that contains definitions such as

```
\newcommand{\myemail}{myemail@campus.edu}
```

and in your documents use

```
\input{myconfig}
```

and then refer to `\myemail` instead of `myemail@campus.edu`.

Whenever you need to change your personal data, edit `myconfig.tex` and recompile all the documents that depend on it.

Comment: This is a really stupid question, but where do/would you save this config file? I.e. where does the LaTeX compiler know to look?

Comment: @Chill2Macht anywhere in your `texmflocal` directory (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/what-are-texlives-four-different-texmf-folders) as long as you run `texhash` after placing it there.