# Where do I find the source code of beamer in a MiKTeX installation?

Tags: beamer, miktex, sourcecode

I'm looking for the source code of default beamer themes (`*.sty`) for studying purpose.

A file content search for keywords like `\setbeamertemplate` only returns `texworks.exe`.

If these definitions are only shipped as binaries, is there another way to install the source?

Comment: What sort of search did you do? By 'sources' I take it you actually mean the files used by TeX at run-time, not for example the source files for the `beamer` documentation? Probably you are looking for `kpsewhich beamer.cls` or similar.

Comment: If you compile a Beamer document, you can see a few of the files used by studying the log file

Comment: every time you process any latex document the full path of every included file is printed to the log file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The files loaded by TeX to use a LaTeX document class such as `beamer` are text files: there are no binaries involved. If you know the name of the file TeX is loading you can find it using `kpsewhich`. For example, the main `beamer` class file is called `beamer.cls`, and

```
kpsewhich beamer.cls
```

at the Command Line/Terminal will find it. On my system it gives

```
c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
```

Inside the `beamer` folder you will then find other files that come with it: a lot in the case of `beamer`, perhaps no additional files for a lot of packages. (The set up for `beamer` is pretty complex: there are a lot of files to read if you want to find a particular piece of code.)

(Class files all have extension `.cls`, package files all have extension `.sty` that's built-in to the LaTeX kernel, which is called `latex.ltx` should you wish to read that! The `beamer` theme files have a naming pattern `beamer<type>theme<name>.sty`, so for example the  'Seagull' colour theme is defined by `beamercolorthemeseagull.sty`.)

Some document classes and packages use a source/extracted approach where the sources may not be directly usable. They might be found using `kpsewhich`, for example

```
kpsewhich siunitx.dtx
```

gives me

```
c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/source/latex/siunitx/siunitx.dtx
```

Note that `beamer` *doesn't* use such sources so this won't show anything. Also notice that MiKTeX and TeX Live have a different approach to the source files: TeX Live includes them all unzipped and so easy-to-find, while in MiKTeX most of the sources are compressed inside `<installation root>\source`.

As noted in a comment, the `.log` file generated by TeX includes the location of each file loaded. MiKTeX always gives the full path for these, while TeX Live gives relative paths where appropriate (making it a bit easier to read in some cases).

Answer (score 7):

It's `texmf\source\beamer-src.tar.bz2`, where `texmf` has to be replaced with the main root of your installation — usually `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9` for a 64 bit installation, or `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9` for a 32 bit installation.

Generally speaking (almost) all sources are installed in `Main Root\source`. The exact location can be checked, for a particular package, with MiKTeX Package Manager: right-click on the package name and select the `Files` tab; a popup window will show the list of all files in the package, ordered by path, such as this one:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The MiKTeX Package Manager shows a relative path: `texmf\tex\latex\beamer\base\ ` (wherein `texmf` seems to be a [placeholder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12701/45610)), while `kpsewhich` gives an absolute path, like: `C:/Users/Jens/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamer.cls`.

Comment: Such a path corresponds to a personal installation. For an installation for every user, `texmf` is `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX` by default.