# Is there an EASY step by step guide to installing packages?

Tags: packages

Im trying to install a package, the one called "mathtools".
I am using MikTeX and Texmaker, and the Package Manager does not work, so i need to do it manually.

I have downloaded a folder from CTAN and that gave me a folder filled with some files.
empheq.dtx, empheq.pdf, mathtools.dtx, mathtools.pdf, mhsetup.dtx, mhsetup.pdf and README.

In the README file it says to "run TeX on each dtx file" but i have no idea what this means. Please write a rookiefriendly guide like, open program X, use the button X etc. 
I won't understand if you just say "well just use TeX on it." I am really bad at this.

Hope you can help me, all i want is to use latex but it won't let me.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but... "The package manager does not work" - In what way?

Comment: @darthbith if i install "mathtools" from package manager and try to build in TeXmaker, it still says it is missing "mathtools.sty". So i just take it, that it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome here. Did you have installed a TeX distro previously? Could be that texmaker uses this one and keep updating the newer one. Please add `\listfiles` at the beginning of your document and check the log-file.

Comment: @Johannes_B what am i looking for in the log file?

Comment: `\listfiles` won't be of any help, sorry. But when the LaTeX opens a file (package, class, etc) it writes it's path to the logfile. Do you know where you installed MikTeX? Compare with the logfile for any differences.

Comment: You can choose a mirror with the MikTeX package manager, there is a chance that this mirror decided to be non-working today. There is a list somewhere on the miktex homepage.

Answer (score 3):

The comments above suggest that there may be a way to solve your problem without learning how to manually install LaTeX packages. But, it's not a bad idea to know how for troubleshooting, and quick fixes.

Overview:

1. create a TDS directory structure (once)
2. place mathtools directory inside (most packages should go in `latex/`)
3. run `tex` on `.dtx` files (creating `.sty` files)

   1. (I think I've more often seen `latex <some package>.ins`)
4. (Optional) further cleanup towards TDS conventions

You'll want to create a `texmf` directory. Determining where to put it, that is, the default location, in Windows, is discussed here: [packages - Where is texmf on a Windows install - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12701/where-is-texmf-on-a-windows-install).

So in your explorer, you'll want to head to your home directory, and create directories until you have the following chain:

```
c:\Users\<your user name>\texmf\tex\latex\
```

You would put the `mathtools` directory there, so that you have for instance

```
c:\Users\<your user name>\texmf\tex\latex\mathtools\mathtools.dtx
```

Now, open up a command prompt, and `cd` (change directory) to this location, that is,

```
cd c:\Users\<your user name>\texmf\tex\latex\mathtools\
```

From there, run `tex` on the appropriate files, that is, type

```
tex mathtools.dtx
```

You may also need

```
tex empheq.dtx
```

This will create the style files, `mathtools.sty` and `empheq.sty`.

*This is enough.* Latex may now know where to find the style files because of TDS (TeX directory structure). If it does not, you many have to run `texhash` or similar.

You could follow convention further, cleaning up, putting the documentation (pdfs) into `texmf\doc\mathtools\`, and put the `.dtx` (and sometimes `.ins`) files into some source directory for easy access if you want to recover them later (without internet?).

Comment: @Johannes_B, Oh, thank you, honest mistake. The directory as he describes it has no `.ins` nor `.sty` files, perhaps part of the problem. Will check out CTAN.

Comment: Just checked, you ned to run `tex` on both `dtx` files. The dtx describes a way »If you insist on using LaTeX« as well.

Comment: I was commenting prematurely ;-)

Comment: Additionally, i think MikTeX has its *Refresh FNDB* (file name data base) which is a one-click synonym for `texhash` (not sure).

Comment: @Johannes_B, thanks, you were right, I changed commands `latex` to `tex` and it created the `.sty` files. Perhaps there is some literate programming and tangling going on there, regarding your earlier suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Johannes_B, this is not right, I read too quickly. I'm just discovering now, apparently the `.dtx` file is commented source. The `.ins` are installation instructions to speed up removal of those comments. Which is why we often simply `tex` the `.ins` file. Somehow, I was imagining the `.pdf` documentation would also come from the `.dtx` file. But no, I expect that typically comes from a separate `.tex` file. So not quite literate programming. We might almost say we "tangle" the code out of the `.dtx` file. But we don't also "weave" the `.pdf` from the same.

Comment: Usually (in my experience) the ins (running tex/latex on it) extracts the package and running latex/pdflatex on the dtx gives the doc. For the doc it is the case.