# Justified alignment for equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I am writing a IEEE journal paper full of equations and with center alignment the paper looks so messy.

[image]

I needed to justified align at least those that are coming successively one after another. I want equations at the left of the line but their numbers at the right.

Currently I am using these codes

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_33}
UR_i=DR_i=\dfrac{P_i^{max}}{2} \qquad \textrm{(MW/min)} \quad\forall i\\
\end{equation}
```

which is centering alignment.

Comment: Either use the `fleqn` option in your document class, or use one of `flalign`, `flalign*` environments from `amsmath`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide compilable code but not snippets. Do you want to have all equations aligned to the left or just one? Or are you talking about the `align` environment? Please clarify. If you are using a template like `IEEEtran`, you maybe mustn't change their style scheme.

Comment: @Bernard none of these works if the OP is using `IEEEtran`. Well, lets wait for the MWE.

Comment: If the article is being prepared for publication in an IEEE journal then the setting of equation by the 'IEEEtran' class should not be altered.

Comment: Regarding your edit. Yes, it does look messy. You should use `align` for most of your equations, maybe do not number all of them but just the important ones. And you should write a little text in between (`\shortintertext` or alike).

Comment: Can you please check the image I just added and guide me is it natural for equations to look like that?

Comment: What about using \subequation, isn't a better idea and is it also center-justified?

Comment: Can't answer that. This depends very much on the meaning of your equations. You have to guide the reader in order to make him understand your math. If the equations are just transformations, give just a number to the last line (or vertically centred). If they are alternatives, you could label a and b... If they are all completely different and important formulae, you are just fine, but without some inter-text, I would turn the page to see if the next one gets easier :-)

Comment: I have NOMENCLATURE section to describe symbols and thses equations are the constraints of an optimization problem and all important

Comment: Well, this page does not look like constraints but like a formulae collection. You already noticed your self that it looks unattractive... So imagine the reader who is new to this stuff. If you really need this list of singular equations, you could use an itemize or a left-aligned table (with less horizontal lines as on the right...). You are the typesetter so think of something to make it beautiful. If you just write "Doing that", "which yields", "finally resulting in", "leads to",... it will look better and the reading will be a pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this, as it is not the recommended style by IEEE, but you can change this globally with the following MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{blindtext} % for demo only
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol-or-fraction]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_33}
UR_i=DR_i=\frac{P_i^\text{max}}{2}\,\si{\mega\watt\per\minute}\qquad\forall i
\end{equation}
Which results in \SI{42}{\mega\watt\per\minute} \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using TexStudio and how can I add  package mathtools, usually they are downloaded automatically but this one is seems it didn't happen

Comment: [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187725), [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199883), [3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200714)...

Comment: `$\forall i$` should go before, not after, the rest of the equation.  It's a mathematical symbol and not simply shorthand for the words `for all.'