# Location of pdflatex when installing Lyx

Tags: pdftex, lyx, windows

Where is the location of pdflatex when installed through Lyx on Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is "texmf" on a Windows install?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12701/where-is-texmf-on-a-windows-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern Versions of Windows - since Windows 7 - have the `where` command installed. It checks whether an executable is in one of the folders that is listed in your $PATH.

Enter the command on the cmd or in Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\me> where.exe pdflatex
C:\texlive\2016\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe
```

If Lyx installs pdflatex on the $PATH, you should be able to find it with this method.