# Where is texmf.cnf in Windows 10 and Miktex 2.9?

Tags: miktex2.9

i read some guide about texmf.cnf but i don't find this file in my computer (Windows 10 & Miktex2.9, Texmarker).

Please guide me where this file is and how can i edit this file?
Ex:

main_memory=5000000

extra_mem_bot=5000000

font_mem_size=5000000

pool_size=5000000

buf_size=5000000

save_size  = 100000

From this topic: [Where is "texmf" on a Windows install?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12701/where-is-texmf-on-a-windows-install)

i type both type  at the command prompt but no effort:

kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME

Alternatively:

kpsewhich -expand-var '$TEXMFHOME'

[image]
Thanks

Comment: miktex doesn't have a texmf.cnf, its configuration is done differently. See https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/runtimeparams.html

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher: Thanks, i can edit "pdflatex.ini": main_memory=5000000 
extra_mem_bot=5000000 
font_mem_size=5000000 
pool_size=5000000 
buf_size=5000000. But can not compile. Error: File not found. What is happen? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you did wrong.